# Why is my APK so large?

Tags: java, android, git, apk

My APK is coming out to around 19 MB. I have no pictures or sound files in my project and only one class. Looking through the directory of my project folder (which is about 50 MB), most of the size seems to be coming from the .git folder in my src folder, and the .git folder in my bin folder, but I am under the impression that the .git folder is not included in the final APK. Does anyone know what could be causing this large size? I have tried cleaning the project as well with no luck. I am not referencing any other libraries, and my only private library is Google AdMobs. I am also using ProGuard.

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?

Comment: Why is there a `.git` folder in your `bin` folder?

Comment: @jlordo Not really sure - that's just the way it's always been for me. Is that not how it should be?

Comment: Open your .apk as a zip file (rename a copy to .zip if you can't do so otherwise) and see what is taking up the space.

Comment: have you enabled proguard in release mode??

Comment: @ChrisStratton Let me take a look.

Comment: @ChrisStratton So, apparently, the .git folder does end up in the final APK. Most of the size is coming from com->.git->objects and com->.git->modules. I notice that modules contains only one folder called ActionBarSherlock, which I was using, but removed for the time being to see what my size would be without it, so I have no idea why it's there.

Comment: @JohnRoberts: I don't see a good reason for having the binaries in version control...

Comment: @jlordo I don't really know what to do about it. My project folder is managed by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to init your git repository on your project's root folder and not on the src folder. The project's root folder is the one where the AndroidManifest.xml is located!

The .git folder is where all the git version control files are stored and it gets bigger as the project is developed.

Comment: So can I literally just cut and paste it?

Comment: It is not as easy as cut and paste. If you wish to maintain the version control you should do what is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614229/can-i-move-the-git-directory-for-a-repo-to-its-parent-directory

Comment: Or you could start a new version control on the root folder and delete the existing one on the src folder (and you will lose the current version control).

Comment: What if I'm not using git at all for my project? I've only used Eclipse up to this point. Can I just get rid of it altogether?

Comment: If you are not using git, you can delete the .git folder!

Comment: Haha, nice man. The size just went from 19 megabytes to 190 KB.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Android Size Analyzer. Details on this page: [reduce-apk-size](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size)