# Rebase Conflicts Pulling One Repo Into Another

Tags: git

I am following the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/614254/400723 in order to combine 3 git repos into a single one. Unfortunately, while pulling in the 3rd, I am getting a significant number of conflicts. These repos should not have any overlap with the files that they touch, is there something I'm missing?

I created "proj-parent" and checked out the three repos into it: api, import, and commons. I did the filter-branch command and everything was fine. I pulled in commons first and then import (which had a few conflicts). I am trying to do a git pull on api now and there are a significant number of conflicts (most of them with import). Did I do something wrong? There should be virtually no overlap with the files that these projects touch as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the the [`-s recursive -Xours`](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies) option for [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).

This option does the following:

> ...This option forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by
>   favoring 'our' version. Changes from the other tree that do not
>   conflict with our side are reflected to the merge result. For a binary
>   file, the entire contents are taken from our side...

Anywhere there would be a conflict (both versions changing the same content), it will auto-select the `HEADs` version and continue to move on automatically. It auto merges everything else just as if it were a normal merge.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying this now and will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Turns out I actually wanted -Xtheirs but that was my error not yours. ;)