# How do you merge two Git repositories?

Tags: git, merge, repository, git-subtree

Consider the following scenario:

I have developed a small experimental project A in its own Git repo. It has now matured, and I'd like A to be part of larger project B, which has its own big repository. I'd now like to add A as a subdirectory of B.

How do I merge A into B, without losing history on any side?

Comment: If you're just trying to combine two repositories into one, without needing to keep both repositories, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history/

Answer (score 520, accepted):

A single branch of another repository can be easily placed under a subdirectory retaining its history. For example:

```
git subtree add --prefix=rails git://github.com/rails/rails.git master
```

This will appear as a single commit where all files of Rails master branch are added into "rails" directory.
However the commit's title contains a reference to the old history tree:

> Add 'rails/' from commit `<rev>`

Where `<rev>` is a SHA-1 commit hash. You can still see the history, blame some changes.

```
git log <rev>
git blame <rev> -- README.md
```

Note that you can't see the directory prefix from here since this is an actual old branch left intact.
You should treat this like a usual file move commit: you will need an extra jump when reaching it.

```
# finishes with all files added at once commit
git log rails/README.md

# then continue from original tree
git log <rev> -- README.md
```

There are more complex solutions like doing this manually or rewriting the history as described in other answers.

The git-subtree command is a part of official git-contrib, some packet managers install it by default (OS X Homebrew).
But you might have to install it by yourself in addition to git.

Comment: Here are instructions on how to install Git SubTree (as of June 2013): http://stackoverflow.com/a/11613541/694469  (and I replaced `git co v1.7.11.3 ` with `... v1.8.3`).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the below answer. As of git 1.8.4 'subtree' still isn't included (at least not on the Ubuntu 12.04 git ppa (ppa:git-core/ppa) )

Comment: I can confirm that after this, `git log rails/somefile` will not display that file's commits history except the merge commit. As @artfulrobot suggested, check [Greg Hewgill's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1425914/532008). And you might need to use `git filter-branch` on the repo you want to include.

Comment: Or read Eric Lee's "Merging Two Git Repositories Into One Repository Without Losing File History" http://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/

Comment: @MattKlein: git subtree is included in the git-core ppa, but not enabled by default. to enable: `chmod +x /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh` then `ln -s /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh /usr/lib/git-core/git-subtree` as root

Comment: As others have said, `git subtree` may not do what you think! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories/21495718#21495718) for a more complete solution.

Comment: Hello. I've took time to expand my answer since the question is so popular. Hopefully it answers many concerns raised here. The most voted answer does not directly answer the question. I'm no git expert and it was long until I figured out this simple command. It is a bummer that some package managers don't install git-contrib.

Comment: Using "git subtree" presumes you're combining the same branch, in this case "master." If you're not, git subtree will fail. You'd have to follow the 2nd set of instructions below.

Comment: Subtree is not works as expected, in this answer after merging all git history leaves original http://stackoverflow.com/a/43340714/1772410

Comment: I was considering editing your answer, but that would probably won't leave much of its current content. So for what it's worth I'm leaving here a [link](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/8ad01701db51ec2891ca431b78c58c72) to my description. I suggest you update your answer yourself.

Answer (score 2836):

If you want to merge `project-a` into `project-b`:

```bash
cd path/to/project-b
git remote add project-a /path/to/project-a
git fetch project-a --tags
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories project-a/master # or any branch you want to merge
git remote remove project-a
```

Taken from: [git merge different repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949738/git-merge-different-repositories)

This method worked pretty well for me, it's shorter and in my opinion a lot cleaner.

In case you want to put `project-a` into a subdirectory, you can use [`git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (`filter-branch` is [discouraged](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning)). Run the following commands before the commands above:

```bash
cd path/to/project-a
git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter project-a
```

An example of merging 2 big repositories, putting one of them into a subdirectory: https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/9890ab1079cf4357d6f269d073fd9731

**Note:** 
The `--allow-unrelated-histories` parameter only exists since git >= 2.9. See [Git - git merge Documentation / --allow-unrelated-histories](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---allow-unrelated-histories)

**Update**: 
Added `--tags` as suggested by @jstadler in order to keep tags.

Comment: it seems this need a working copy: `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`, i want to merge two bare git repository.

Comment: @LiuYan刘研: Sry this comes a bit late but you could create a working copy by checking out one of the projects and then procceed as described.

Comment: Note that this will not merge submodules.

Comment: @PythonNut Could you provide a link to a solution that would or point out which of the other answers would?

Comment: This did the business for me. Worked like a charm first time with only one conflict in the .gitignore file! It perfectly preserved the commit history. The big plus over other approaches - in addition to simplicity - is that with this there need not be an ongoing reference to the merged repo. One thing to watch out for however - if you're an iOS developer like me - is to be very careful to drop in the target repo's project file into the workspace.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. I needed to move the merged directory into a sub-folder so after following the above steps I simply used `git mv source-dir/ dest/new-source-dir`

Comment: @Sid or anyone else, do you know how to place project-a into a subdirectory within project-b in one shot? If both projects have a lot of files in their root directory, it's kind of a pain to sift through all of them and move where necessary

Comment: @sg An indirect way would be to move all those files in project-a into a subdir in project-a (such that the top level of project-a only has that one directory) and then follow the above process.

Comment: After merging, you can also run `git rebase -i [last commit of project-b]` to make the logs look better.

Comment: The `git merge` step fails here with `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`; `--allow-unrelated-histories` fixes that as explained in the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergea).

Comment: Confirmed! Worked like a charm for me. I did not execute the last two lines and did my stuff by sourcetree instead, but the first 3 lines actually does the magic.

Comment: Wtf, this is a superior answer to the main question/title. I guess the accepted and top-voted respondents just picked out that "in a subdirectory" detail in the body text and ran off with it. To me, "merge two Git repositories" means exactly what this answer says, and so far, it seems to be working just fine for me. +1

Comment: This just works with git >2.8 - for linux you need the ppa repository to get it. But after I've fixed this it is the exact solution for what I want. 100% problem solving!

Comment: I got `error: unknown option 'allow-unrelated-histories'`

Comment: But leaving off the `--allow-unrelated-histories` worked

Comment: Shorter: `git fetch /path/to/project-a master; git merge --allow-unrelated-histories FETCH_HEAD`.

Comment: @jthill make it your own answer maybe?

Comment: This is so awesome. I use it to get my old commit history when I veered off onto another branch and forgot to merge my changes back to the base branch. In this case, I don't want to accept any of the changes from the old branch I'm merging, but just get the history. So I use the "ours" merge strategy, `git merge -s ours --allow-unrelated-histories project-a/master` and it works perfectly!

Comment: This worked perfectly. Quick tip for anyone who's doing something similar as I: Before doing the above, I also followed [these instructions](http://www.janosgyerik.com/rewrite-git-history-to-prefix-a-range-of-commit-messages/) to add a prefix like `Project A:` to all of `project-a`'s commit messages, so that the context of the messages would be clear from within `project-b`.

Comment: This was super handy. I use a git version pre 2.9, and I was able to simply perform the remote add and fetch as stated above, then merge the source project directly into the target project. I also found that there was no loss of history as well. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: When fetching you should also consider fetching the tags because otherwise they will get lost:

`git fetch project-a --tags`

Comment: But now, how do you undo that? At my work someone obviously decided to do that at some point in past, with exception that he merged Slim framework repo, so our repository history is barely usable since there is a way to many unrelated commits.

Comment: @xZero That would be a topic for a new, seperate Question. Go create it and link it here

Comment: Saved the day for me. Instead of step 4, I used `git rebase project-a/master` to have a linear history.

Comment: Great answer! Would be nice if you also added a version on how to do it with project A as sub-folder in project B. Where project A has a lot of files in the root.

Comment: I think @Norfeldt asked exactly the same question as the original: "I'd now like to add A as a **subdirectory** of B."

Comment: Is there a way to add prefix into `project-a`'s tags? Because project-a and project-b had similar tags and now I got this `! [rejected]            0.1.0      -> 0.1.0  (would clobber existing tag)` when running `git fetch project-a --tags`

Comment: @ShinebayarG This is a good question. It could be it's own question even?

Comment: @jstadler I'm not sure why you had to pass `--tags` to `git fetch` since that is the default. I can trace it back to at least [year 2007](https://github.com/git/git/commit/02f571c73bfdf1d950848ed24229caea438f1f72) (`git-1.5.0`).

@Shinebayar `git filter-repo --tag-rename :project-a-` See [this](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/9890ab1079cf4357d6f269d073fd9731) for an example.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me; "git merge --allow-unrelated-histories project-a/master" results in "error: unknown option `allow-unrelated-histories'".  My GIT version is 1.8.3.1.

So I tried "git merge project-a/master" (no --allow-unrelated-histories option).  GIT says "fatal: project-a/master - not something we can merge"

I thought you could do a merge w/ older versions of GIT if you don't use the --allow-unrelated-histories option.

How can I get past this problem?

Comment: @SQA777 Maybe post this as a new question, refferencing this answer? I do not know the answer to this and that way it might get better answers and then help others to find those answers in the future? Good Luck!

Comment: @AndreschSerj, I posted my problem as a separate question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67040984/does-a-git-merge-of-unrelated-repos-require-a-certain-version-of-git // Got a few negative feedback.  The answer is slightly incorrect, which I will point out in my subsequent comment.

Comment: The answer doesn't work if you are using a Git version that's earlier than v2.9.  The --allow-unrelated-histories option isn't provided by Git until v2.9.  For earlier versions, you can do a Git merge similar to what @AndreschSerj stated: 1) git remote add project-a /path/to/project-a 2) git fetch project-a  # don't use --tags option 3) git merge project-a/master  4) git remote remove project-a  # This works in moving the files and merging the two separate Git repos.

Comment: Note that `git filter-repo` is not available with the standard Apple development tools on Mojave 10.14.6. The `git` version on this platform is 2.21.1

Comment: `git remote remove project-a` may not be important for everyone. Someone may need to stay in sync with project-a.

Comment: If you are doing this, and also using GIT-LFS, you will be in a world of pain...

Comment: See this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14470212/9944300

Comment: Simple Ubuntu 22.02 install of `get-filter-repo` => `sudo apt-get install git-filter-repo`

Comment: If I understand the syntax of "git remote add" correctly the /path/to/project-a needs to be a URL, not a directory path

Comment: What if project-B has LFS objects? What additional commands would be required?

Comment: @Toral Additional commands may be required only if project-**a** has LFS objects, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77358772/4669135

Answer (score 661):

Here are two possible solutions:

#### Submodules

Either copy repository A into a separate directory in larger project B, or (perhaps better) clone repository A into a subdirectory in project B. Then use [git submodule](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.5.6/git-submodule.html) to make this repository a ***submodule*** of a repository B.

This is a good solution for loosely-coupled repositories, where development in repository A continues, and the major portion of development is a separate stand-alone development in A. See also [SubmoduleSupport](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/SubmoduleSupport) and [GitSubmoduleTutorial](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitSubmoduleTutorial) pages on Git Wiki.

#### Subtree merge

You can merge repository A into a subdirectory of a project B using the ***subtree merge*** strategy. This is described in [*Subtree Merging and You*](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/subtree-merging-and-you/) by Markus Prinz.

```
git remote add -f Bproject /path/to/B
git merge -s ours --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit Bproject/master
git read-tree --prefix=dir-B/ -u Bproject/master
git commit -m "Merge B project as our subdirectory"
git pull -s subtree Bproject master
```

(Option `--allow-unrelated-histories` is needed for Git >= 2.9.0.)

Or you can use **git subtree** tool ([repository on GitHub](http://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree)) by apenwarr (Avery Pennarun), announced for example in his blog post [A new alternative to Git submodules: git subtree](http://apenwarr.ca/log/?m=200904#30).

---

*I think in your case (A is to be part of larger project B) the correct solution would be to use **subtree merge***.

Comment: I found everything I needed to put my local repo in a subdirectory of a remote repo following the "how to use the subtree merge strategy" HOWTO.

Comment: hmm 'git pull -s subtree Bproject master' doesn't update the Bproject/master tag in the history to the new Bproject HEAD

Comment: This works and seems to preserve the history, but not such that you could use it to diff files or bisect through the merge.  Am I missing a step?

Comment: **this is incomplete**. Yes you get a load of commits, but they no longer refer to the right paths. `git log dir-B/somefile` won't show anything except the one merge. See [Greg Hewgill's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1425914/623519) references this important issue.

Comment: apenwarr's `git subtree split` tool is now in mainline git as of [1.7.11](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/THIS-REPO-IS-OBSOLETE)

Comment: IMPORTANT: git pull --no-rebase -s subtree Bproject master  If you don't do that, and you have pull set to rebase automatically, you'll end up with "Could not parse object".  See http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-07/msg01576.html

Comment: This answer may be confusing because it has B as the merged subtree when in the question it was A. Result of a copy and paste?

Comment: @artfulrobot Yes I have just experienced the same problem, git log is broken on the files from project B, and lots of commits have been pushed to the mixed repo, I wonder if someone happens to have some way to fix the problem? thx.

Comment: If you're trying to simply glue two repositories together, submodules and subtree merges are the wrong tool to use because they don't preserve all of the file history (as other commenters have noted).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history/.

Comment: There’s also `git stree` – supposedly better than `subtree`: https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec.

Answer (score 214):

The submodule approach is good if you want to maintain the project separately. However, if you really want to merge both projects into the same repository, then you have a bit more work to do.

The first thing would be to use `git filter-branch` to rewrite the names of everything in the second repository to be in the subdirectory where you would like them to end up. So instead of `foo.c`, `bar.html`, you would have `projb/foo.c` and `projb/bar.html`.

Then, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
git remote add projb [wherever]
git pull projb
```

The `git pull` will do a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. There should be no conflicts, if the repository you're pulling to does not yet have a `projb/` directory.

Further searching indicates that something similar was done to merge `gitk` into `git`. Junio C Hamano writes about it here: http://www.mail-archive.com/git@vger.kernel.org/msg03395.html

Comment: Not having tried this myself, the `git pull` step may complain about the inability to find a common ancestor. Some other details may need to be ironed out too.

Comment: subtree merge would be better solution, and do not require rewriting history of included project

Comment: I'd like to know how to use `git filter-branch` to achieve this. In the man page it says about the opposite way around: making subdir/ become the root, but not the other way around.

Comment: @artfulrobot: Definitely look at [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) for tools that can help do this (git-subtree was recently added to the standard Git distribution, too).

Comment: this answer would be great if it explained how to use filter-branch to achieve the desired result

Comment: I found how to use filter-branch here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042816/how-can-i-rewrite-history-so-that-all-files-are-in-a-subdirectory

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories/21495718#21495718) for the implementation of Greg's outline.

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories#answer-618113) a much more detailed explanation of what I believe is the same solution.

Comment: Tried this, and ended up with this error:
"You asked to pull from the remote '<my other project>', but did not specify a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line."

Comment: For anyone looking for a `git filter-branch` example to move the root into a subdirectory: `git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git ls-files -s | awk -v prefix="SUBDIRECTORY/" "{ sub(/\t/, \"\t\" prefix); print}" | GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD` (replace SUBDIRECTORY with actual directory name)

Comment: Really, there are no conflicts. Because the second project is not merged at all. Maybe it worked on some old versions...

Comment: This answer is good however I'm wondering what changes do I need to make for gitFlow.  I have in-flight feature, develop, release branches that would also need the treatment. Is it simply a matter of rinse and repeat across all active branches?

Answer (score 82):

**`git-subtree` is nice, but it is probably not the one you want.**

For example, if `projectA` is the directory created in B, after `git subtree`,

```
git log projectA
```

lists **only one** commit: the merge. The commits from the merged project are for different paths, so they don't show up.

Greg Hewgill's answer comes closest, although it doesn't actually say how to rewrite the paths.

---

The solution is surprisingly simple.

(1) In A,

```
PREFIX=projectA #adjust this

git filter-branch --index-filter '
    git ls-files -s |
    sed "s,\t,&'"$PREFIX"'/," |
    GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info &&
    mv $GIT_INDEX_FILE.new $GIT_INDEX_FILE
' HEAD
```

Note: This rewrites history; you may want to first make a backup of A.

*Note Bene: You have to modify the substitute script inside the sed command in the case that you use non-ascii characters (or white characters) in file names or path. In that case the file location inside a record produced by "ls-files -s" begins with quotation mark.*

(2) Then in B, run

```
git pull path/to/A
```

Voila! You have a `projectA` directory in B. If you run `git log projectA`, you will see all commits from A.

---

In my case, I wanted two subdirectories, `projectA` and `projectB`. In that case, I did step (1) to B as well.

Comment: It looks like you copied your answer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/618113/586086?

Comment: @AndrewMao, I think so...I actually can't remember. I've used this script quite a bit.

Comment: The original is on http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch anyway, which is linked to by the other question. It makes for an interesting, if confusing read.

Comment: I'd add that \t doesn't work on OS X and you have to enter <tab>

Comment: This worked great, although on Windows I needed to put the script in a separate file and call it like this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798142/error-combining-git-repositories-into-subdirs

Comment: `"$GIT_INDEX_FILE"` must be quoted (twice), otherwise your method will fail if e.g. the path contains spaces.

Comment: If you're wondering, to insert a <tab> in osx, you need to `Ctrl-V <tab>`

Comment: "Note: This rewrites history, so if you intend to continue using this repo B, you may want to clone (copy) a throwaway copy of it first."

Doesn't that step only rewrite history in A?

Comment: @JosephBlair, yes. "using this repo B" should have been "using this repo A". Fixed.

Comment: I couldn't make this work for me properly on OSX, but this one did: https://gist.github.com/fabiomaggio/ce7ecd7dffd27b32a45325204288efce

Comment: I got two errors on the `git pull` step.  First, "fatal: 'projectB' does not appear to be a git repository  fatal: Could not read from remote repository."  This was solved by using the **absolute path**, i.e. `/path/to/A`.  Next, I got: `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`.  This seems to happen [since git v2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37938036/1386750), and can be solved by specifying `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories /path/to/A`.

Comment: I got 'fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories` during the pull step. I had to do `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories /path/to/A` instead.

Comment: It's not that the history isn't there, its just that `git log` doesn't show it when looking at the history of just that sub-directory. Subtree doesn't rewrite the commits so the trees of the merged commits are still at the "root". At the end of the day, its a trade-off -- maintain the history (and commit hashes) "as-is" with subtree, but recognize that older commits maintain their old trees, or rewrite the trees of older commits, so that the history appears as if the repo has always existed with the current structure.

Answer (score 68):

If both repositories have same kind of files (like two Rails repositories for different projects), you can fetch data of the secondary repository to your current repository:

```
git fetch git://repository.url/repo.git master:branch_name
```

and then merge it to current repository:

```
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories branch_name
```

If your Git version is smaller than 2.9, remove `--allow-unrelated-histories`.

After this, conflicts may occur. You can resolve them for example with `git mergetool`. `kdiff3` can be used solely with keyboard, so 5 conflict file takes when reading the code just few minutes.

Remember to finish the merge:

```
git commit
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of this solution, and it seems like what I'm looking for, but isn't it basically just equivalent to a `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories`?

Comment: @Prometheus Kind of so. I didn’t test it now, but probably pull would’ve required adding the remote repository as a real remote, where this only fetches the necessary content to a branch and merges that content.

Answer (score 36):

I kept losing history when using merge, so I ended up using rebase since in my case the two repositories are different enough not to end up merging at every commit:

```
git clone git@gitorious/projA.git projA
git clone git@gitorious/projB.git projB

cd projB
git remote add projA ../projA/
git fetch projA 
git rebase projA/master HEAD
```

=> resolve conflicts, then continue, as many times as needed...

```
git rebase --continue
```

Doing this leads to one project having all commits from projA followed by commits from projB

Answer (score 28):

In my case, I had a `my-plugin` repository and a `main-project` repository, and I wanted to pretend that `my-plugin` had always been developed in the `plugins` subdirectory of `main-project`.

Basically, I rewrote the history of the `my-plugin` repository so that it appeared all development took place in the `plugins/my-plugin` subdirectory. Then, I added the development history of `my-plugin` into the `main-project` history, and merged the two trees together. Since there was no `plugins/my-plugin` directory already present in the `main-project` repository, this was a trivial no-conflicts merge. The resulting repository contained all history from both original projects, and had two roots.

## TL;DR

```
$ cp -R my-plugin my-plugin-dirty
$ cd my-plugin-dirty
$ git filter-branch -f --tree-filter "zsh -c 'setopt extended_glob && setopt glob_dots && mkdir -p plugins/my-plugin && (mv ^(.git|plugins) plugins/my-plugin || true)'" -- --all
$ cd ../main-project
$ git checkout master
$ git remote add --fetch my-plugin ../my-plugin-dirty
$ git merge my-plugin/master --allow-unrelated-histories
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf my-plugin-dirty
```

## Long version

First, create a copy of the `my-plugin` repository, because we're going to be rewriting the history of this repository.

Now, navigate to the root of the `my-plugin` repository, check out your main branch (probably `master`), and run the following command. Of course, you should substitute for `my-plugin` and `plugins` whatever your actual names are.

```
$ git filter-branch -f --tree-filter "zsh -c 'setopt extended_glob && setopt glob_dots && mkdir -p plugins/my-plugin && (mv ^(.git|plugins) plugins/my-plugin || true)'" -- --all
```

Now for an explanation. `git filter-branch --tree-filter (...) HEAD` runs the `(...)` command on every commit that is reachable from `HEAD`. Note that this operates directly on the data stored for each commit, so we don't have to worry about notions of "working directory", "index", "staging", and so on.

If you run a `filter-branch` command that fails, it will leave behind some files in the `.git` directory and the next time you try `filter-branch` it will complain about this, unless you supply the `-f` option to `filter-branch`.

As for the actual command, I didn't have much luck getting `bash` to do what I wanted, so instead I use `zsh -c` to make `zsh` execute a command. First I set the `extended_glob` option, which is what enables the `^(...)` syntax in the `mv` command, as well as the `glob_dots` option, which allows me to select dotfiles (such as `.gitignore`) with a glob (`^(...)`).

Next, I use the `mkdir -p` command to create both `plugins` and `plugins/my-plugin` at the same time.

Finally, I use the `zsh` "negative glob" feature `^(.git|plugins)` to match all files in the root directory of the repository except for `.git` and the newly created `my-plugin` folder. (Excluding `.git` might not be necessary here, but trying to move a directory into itself is an error.)

In my repository, the initial commit did not include any files, so the `mv` command returned an error on the initial commit (since nothing was available to move). Therefore, I added a `|| true` so that `git filter-branch` would not abort.

The `--all` option tells `filter-branch` to rewrite the history for *all* branches in the repository, and the extra `--` is necessary to tell `git` to interpret it as a part of the option list for branches to rewrite, instead of as an option to `filter-branch` itself.

Now, navigate to your `main-project` repository and check out whatever branch you want to merge into. Add your local copy of the `my-plugin` repository (with its history modified) as a remote of `main-project` with:

```
$ git remote add --fetch my-plugin $PATH_TO_MY_PLUGIN_REPOSITORY
```

You will now have two unrelated trees in your commit history, which you can visualize nicely using:

```
$ git log --color --graph --decorate --all
```

To merge them, use:

```
$ git merge my-plugin/master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

*Note that in pre-2.9.0 Git, the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option does not exist. If you are using one of these versions, just omit the option: the error message that `--allow-unrelated-histories` prevents was* also *added in 2.9.0.*

You should not have any merge conflicts. If you do, it probably means that either the `filter-branch` command did not work correctly or there was already a `plugins/my-plugin` directory in `main-project`.

Make sure to enter an explanatory commit message for any future contributors wondering what hackery was going on to make a repository with two roots.

You can visualize the new commit graph, which should have two root commits, using the above `git log` command. Note that **only the `master` branch will be merged**. This means that if you have important work on other `my-plugin` branches that you want to merge into the `main-project` tree, you should refrain from deleting the `my-plugin` remote until you have done these merges. If you don't, then the commits from those branches will still be in the `main-project` repository, but some will be unreachable and susceptible to eventual garbage collection. (Also, you will have to refer to them by SHA, because deleting a remote removes its remote-tracking branches.)

Optionally, after you have merged everything you want to keep from `my-plugin`, you can remove the `my-plugin` remote using:

```
$ git remote remove my-plugin
```

You can now safely delete the copy of the `my-plugin` repository whose history you changed. In my case, I also added a deprecation notice to the real `my-plugin` repository after the merge was complete and pushed.

---

Tested on Mac OS X El Capitan with `git --version 2.9.0` and `zsh --version 5.2`. Your mileage may vary.

References:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6393/how-do-you-move-all-files-including-hidden-from-one-directory-to-another
- http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/37/ZSH-Gem-2-Extended-globbing-and-expansion/
- [Purging file from Git repo failed, unable to create new backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403601/purging-file-from-git-repo-failed-unable-to-create-new-backup)
- [git, filter-branch on all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430717/git-filter-branch-on-all-branches)

Comment: Where `--allow-unrelated-histories` are coming from?

Comment: @MarceloFilho Check `man git-merge`. _By default, git merge command refuses to merge histories that do not share a common ancestor. This option can be used to override this safety when merging histories of two projects that started their lives independently. As that is a very rare occasion, no configuration variable to enable this by default exists and will not be added._

Comment: Should be available on `git version 2.7.2.windows.1`?

Comment: @MarceloFilho This was added in 2.9.0, but in older versions you shouldn't have to pass the option (it will just work). https://github.com/git/git/blob/a28705da929ad746abcb34270947f738549d3246/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt#L11

Comment: This worked well.  And I was able to use the filter branch to rewrite the file names to where I wanted in the tree prior to the merge.  I'm supposing there's more work involved if you need to move the history besides the master branch.

Comment: @codeDr I have updated my answer to address the problem of rewriting all branches.

Comment: This generally works well. But, does it rewrite the tags properly? I'm getting
`Ref 'refs/tags/v1.0' was rewritten
WARNING: You said to rewrite tagged commits, but not the corresponding tag.
WARNING: Perhaps use '--tag-name-filter cat' to rewrite the tag.`
in one of my repos. When I checkout the tag, all the contents are in main directory.

Comment: adding `--tag-name-filter cat` to the `filter-branch` command rewrites the tags correctly. So the third command should read `$ git filter-branch -f --tag-name-filter cat --tree-filter "zsh -c 'setopt extended_glob && setopt glob_dots && mkdir -p plugins/my-plugin && (mv ^(.git|plugins) plugins/my-plugin || true)'" -- --all`

Answer (score 10):

I have gathered a lot of information here on Stack OverFlow, etc., and have manage to put a script together which solves the problem for me.

The caveat is that it only takes into account the 'develop' branch of each repository and merges it into a separate directory in a completely new repository.

Tags and other branches are ignored - this might not be what you want.

The script even handles feature branches and tags - renaming them in the new project so you know where they came from.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
################################################################################
## Script to merge multiple git repositories into a new repository
## - The new repository will contain a folder for every merged repository
## - The script adds remotes for every project and then merges in every branch
##   and tag. These are renamed to have the origin project name as a prefix
##
## Usage: mergeGitRepositories.sh <new_project> <my_repo_urls.lst>
## - where <new_project> is the name of the new project to create
## - and <my_repo_urls.lst> is a file contaning the URLs to the respositories
##   which are to be merged on separate lines.
##
## Author: Robert von Burg
##            eitch@eitchnet.ch
##
## Version: 0.3.2
## Created: 2018-02-05
##
################################################################################
#

# disallow using undefined variables
shopt -s -o nounset

# Script variables
declare SCRIPT_NAME="${0##*/}"
declare SCRIPT_DIR="$(cd ${0%/*} ; pwd)"
declare ROOT_DIR="$PWD"
IFS=$'\n'

# Detect proper usage
if [ "$#" -ne "2" ] ; then
  echo -e "ERROR: Usage: $0 <new_project> <my_repo_urls.lst>"
  exit 1
fi


## Script variables
PROJECT_NAME="${1}"
PROJECT_PATH="${ROOT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}"
TIMESTAMP="$(date +%s)"
LOG_FILE="${ROOT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_merge.${TIMESTAMP}.log"
REPO_FILE="${2}"
REPO_URL_FILE="${ROOT_DIR}/${REPO_FILE}"


# Script functions
function failed() {
  echo -e "ERROR: Merging of projects failed:"
  echo -e "ERROR: Merging of projects failed:" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
  echo -e "$1"
  exit 1
}

function commit_merge() {
  current_branch="$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)"
  if [[ ! -f ".git/MERGE_HEAD" ]] ; then
    echo -e "INFO:   No commit required."
    echo -e "INFO:   No commit required." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
  else
    echo -e "INFO:   Committing ${sub_project}..."
    echo -e "INFO:   Committing ${sub_project}..." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
    if ! git commit -m "[Project] Merged branch '$1' of ${sub_project}" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1 ; then
      failed "Failed to commit merge of branch '$1' of ${sub_project} into ${current_branch}"
    fi
  fi
}


# Make sure the REPO_URL_FILE exists
if [ ! -e "${REPO_URL_FILE}" ] ; then
  echo -e "ERROR: Repo file ${REPO_URL_FILE} does not exist!"
  exit 1
fi


# Make sure the required directories don't exist
if [ -e "${PROJECT_PATH}" ] ; then
  echo -e "ERROR: Project ${PROJECT_NAME} already exists!"
  exit 1
fi


# create the new project
echo -e "INFO: Logging to ${LOG_FILE}"
echo -e "INFO: Creating new git repository ${PROJECT_NAME}..."
echo -e "INFO: Creating new git repository ${PROJECT_NAME}..." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
echo -e "===================================================="
echo -e "====================================================" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
cd ${ROOT_DIR}
mkdir ${PROJECT_NAME}
cd ${PROJECT_NAME}
git init
echo "Initial Commit" > initial_commit
# Since this is a new repository we need to have at least one commit
# thus were we create temporary file, but we delete it again.
# Deleting it guarantees we don't have conflicts later when merging
git add initial_commit
git commit --quiet -m "[Project] Initial Master Repo Commit"
git rm --quiet initial_commit
git commit --quiet -m "[Project] Initial Master Repo Commit"
echo


# Merge all projects into the branches of this project
echo -e "INFO: Merging projects into new repository..."
echo -e "INFO: Merging projects into new repository..." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
echo -e "===================================================="
echo -e "====================================================" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
for url in $(cat ${REPO_URL_FILE}) ; do

  if [[ "${url:0:1}" == '#' ]] ; then
    continue
  fi

  # extract the name of this project
  export sub_project=${url##*/}
  sub_project=${sub_project%*.git}

  echo -e "INFO: Project ${sub_project}"
  echo -e "INFO: Project ${sub_project}" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
  echo -e "----------------------------------------------------"
  echo -e "----------------------------------------------------" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1

  # Fetch the project
  echo -e "INFO:   Fetching ${sub_project}..."
  echo -e "INFO:   Fetching ${sub_project}..." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
  git remote add "${sub_project}" "${url}"
  if ! git fetch --tags --quiet ${sub_project} >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1 ; then
    failed "Failed to fetch project ${sub_project}"
  fi

  # add remote branches
  echo -e "INFO:   Creating local branches for ${sub_project}..."
  echo -e "INFO:   Creating local branches for ${sub_project}..." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
  while read branch ; do
    branch_ref=$(echo $branch | tr " " "\t" | cut -f 1)
    branch_name=$(echo $branch | tr " " "\t" | cut -f 2 | cut -d / -f 3-)

    echo -e "INFO:   Creating branch ${branch_name}..."
    echo -e "INFO:   Creating branch ${branch_name}..." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1

    # create and checkout new merge branch off of master
    if ! git checkout -b "${sub_project}/${branch_name}" master >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1 ; then failed "Failed preparing ${branch_name}" ; fi
    if ! git reset --hard ; then failed "Failed preparing ${branch_name}" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1 ; fi
    if ! git clean -d --force ; then failed "Failed preparing ${branch_name}" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1 ; fi

    # Merge the project
    echo -e "INFO:   Merging ${sub_project}..."
    echo -e "INFO:   Merging ${sub_project}..." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
    if ! git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit "remotes/${sub_project}/${branch_name}" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1 ; then
      failed "Failed to merge branch 'remotes/${sub_project}/${branch_name}' from ${sub_project}"
    fi

    # And now see if we need to commit (maybe there was a merge)
    commit_merge "${sub_project}/${branch_name}"

    # relocate projects files into own directory
    if [ "$(ls)" == "${sub_project}" ] ; then
      echo -e "WARN:   Not moving files in branch ${branch_name} of ${sub_project} as already only one root level."
      echo -e "WARN:   Not moving files in branch ${branch_name} of ${sub_project} as already only one root level." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
    else
      echo -e "INFO:   Moving files in branch ${branch_name} of ${sub_project} so we have a single directory..."
      echo -e "INFO:   Moving files in branch ${branch_name} of ${sub_project} so we have a single directory..." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
      mkdir ${sub_project}
      for f in $(ls -a) ; do
        if  [[ "$f" == "${sub_project}" ]] ||
            [[ "$f" == "." ]] ||
            [[ "$f" == ".." ]] ; then
          continue
        fi
        git mv -k "$f" "${sub_project}/"
      done

      # commit the moving
      if ! git commit --quiet -m  "[Project] Move ${sub_project} files into sub directory" ; then
        failed "Failed to commit moving of ${sub_project} files into sub directory"
      fi
    fi
    echo
  done < <(git ls-remote --heads ${sub_project})


  # checkout master of sub probject
  if ! git checkout "${sub_project}/master" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1 ; then
    failed "sub_project ${sub_project} is missing master branch!"
  fi

  # copy remote tags
  echo -e "INFO:   Copying tags for ${sub_project}..."
  echo -e "INFO:   Copying tags for ${sub_project}..." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
  while read tag ; do
    tag_ref=$(echo $tag | tr " " "\t" | cut -f 1)
    tag_name_unfixed=$(echo $tag | tr " " "\t" | cut -f 2 | cut -d / -f 3)

    # hack for broken tag names where they are like 1.2.0^{} instead of just 1.2.0
    tag_name="${tag_name_unfixed%%^*}"

    tag_new_name="${sub_project}/${tag_name}"
    echo -e "INFO:     Copying tag ${tag_name_unfixed} to ${tag_new_name} for ref ${tag_ref}..."
    echo -e "INFO:     Copying tag ${tag_name_unfixed} to ${tag_new_name} for ref ${tag_ref}..." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
    if ! git tag "${tag_new_name}" "${tag_ref}" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1 ; then
      echo -e "WARN:     Could not copy tag ${tag_name_unfixed} to ${tag_new_name} for ref ${tag_ref}"
      echo -e "WARN:     Could not copy tag ${tag_name_unfixed} to ${tag_new_name} for ref ${tag_ref}" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
    fi
  done < <(git ls-remote --tags --refs ${sub_project})

  # Remove the remote to the old project
  echo -e "INFO:   Removing remote ${sub_project}..."
  echo -e "INFO:   Removing remote ${sub_project}..." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
  git remote rm ${sub_project}

  echo
done


# Now merge all project master branches into new master
git checkout --quiet master
echo -e "INFO: Merging projects master branches into new repository..."
echo -e "INFO: Merging projects master branches into new repository..." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
echo -e "===================================================="
echo -e "====================================================" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
for url in $(cat ${REPO_URL_FILE}) ; do

  if [[ ${url:0:1} == '#' ]] ; then
    continue
  fi

  # extract the name of this project
  export sub_project=${url##*/}
  sub_project=${sub_project%*.git}

  echo -e "INFO:   Merging ${sub_project}..."
  echo -e "INFO:   Merging ${sub_project}..." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
  if ! git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit "${sub_project}/master" >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1 ; then
    failed "Failed to merge branch ${sub_project}/master into master"
  fi

  # And now see if we need to commit (maybe there was a merge)
  commit_merge "${sub_project}/master"

  echo
done


# Done
cd ${ROOT_DIR}
echo -e "INFO: Done."
echo -e "INFO: Done." >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
echo

exit 0
```

You can also get it from http://paste.ubuntu.com/11732805

First create a file with the URL to each repository, e.g.:

```
git@github.com:eitchnet/ch.eitchnet.parent.git
git@github.com:eitchnet/ch.eitchnet.utils.git
git@github.com:eitchnet/ch.eitchnet.privilege.git
```

Then call the script giving a name of the project and the path to the script:

```
./mergeGitRepositories.sh eitchnet_test eitchnet.lst
```

The script itself has a lot of comments which should explain what it does.

Comment: Instead of directing readers to an answer, please post the answer here (aka edit what you said in that comment into this answer).

Comment: Sure, just thought it better not to repeat myself... =)

Comment: If you think this question is identical to the other one, then you can flag it as a duplicate using the "flag" link under the question itself and indicating the other question. If it's not a duplicate question but you think the exact same answer can be used to solve both issues, then just post the same answer to both issues (as you have now done). Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Amazing! Did not work on Windows bash prompt, but it ran flawlessly form a Vagrant box running ubuntu. What a time saver!

Comment: Old but.. Maybe it's a good idea to put in bold (and/or bigger font size) the caveat(s)?

Comment: In case anyone gets the "no common commits" error I got. I solved that by adding "--force" to the git fetch command.

Answer (score 10):

I've been trying to do the same thing for days, I am using git 2.7.2. Subtree does not preserve the history.

You can use this method if you will not be using the old project again.

I would suggest that you branch B first and work in the branch.

Here are the steps without branching:

```
cd B

# You are going to merge A into B, so first move all of B's files into a sub dir
mkdir B

# Move all files to B, till there is nothing in the dir but .git and B
git mv <files> B

git add .

git commit -m "Moving content of project B in preparation for merge from A"


# Now merge A into B
git remote add -f A <A repo url>

git merge A/<branch>

mkdir A

# move all the files into subdir A, excluding .git
git mv <files> A

git commit -m "Moved A into subdir"


# Move B's files back to root    
git mv B/* ./

rm -rf B

git commit -m "Reset B to original state"

git push
```

If you now log any of the files in subdir A you will get the full history

```
git log --follow A/<file>
```

This was the post that help me do this:

http://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/

Answer (score 10):

If you want to put the files from a branch in repo B in a ***subtree*** of repo A ***and*** also preserve the history, keep reading. (In the example below, I am assuming that we want repo B's master branch merged into repo A's master branch.)

In repo A, first do the following to make repo B available:

```
git remote add B ../B # Add repo B as a new remote.
git fetch B
```

Now we create a brand new branch (with only one commit) in repo A that we call `new_b_root`. The resulting commit will have the files that were committed in the first commit of repo B's master branch but put in a subdirectory called `path/to/b-files/`.

```
git checkout --orphan new_b_root master
git rm -rf . # Remove all files.
git cherry-pick -n `git rev-list --max-parents=0 B/master`
mkdir -p path/to/b-files
git mv README path/to/b-files/
git commit --date="$(git log --format='%ai' $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 B/master))"
```

Explanation: The `--orphan` option to the checkout command checks out the files from A's master branch but doesn't create any commit. We could have selected any commit because next we clear out all the files anyway. Then, without committing yet (`-n`), we cherry-pick the first commit from B's master branch. (The cherry-pick preserves the original commit message which a straight checkout doesn't seem to do.) Then we create the subtree where we want to put all files from repo B. We then have to move all files that were introduced in the cherry-pick to the subtree. In the example above, there's only a `README` file to move. Then we commit our B-repo root commit, and, at the same time, we also preserve the timestamp of the original commit.

Now, we'll create a new `B/master` branch on top of the newly created `new_b_root`. We call the new branch `b`:

```
git checkout -b b B/master
git rebase -s recursive -Xsubtree=path/to/b-files/ new_b_root
```

Now, we merge our `b` branch into `A/master`:

```
git checkout master
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit b
git commit -m 'Merge repo B into repo A.'
```

Finally, you can remove the `B` remote and temporary branches:

```
git remote remove B
git branch -D new_b_root b
```

The final graph will have a structure like this:

[image]

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I really missed in the other answers with "git subtree" or "merge --allow-unrelated-histories" from Andresch Serj that the sub directory didn't have the log.

Answer (score 7):

I know it's long after the fact, but I wasn't happy with the other answers I found here, so I wrote this:

```
me=$(basename $0)

TMP=$(mktemp -d /tmp/$me.XXXXXXXX)
echo 
echo "building new repo in $TMP"
echo
sleep 1

set -e

cd $TMP
mkdir new-repo
cd new-repo
    git init
    cd ..

x=0
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    repo="$1"; shift
    git clone "$repo"
    dirname=$(basename $repo | sed -e 's/\s/-/g')
    if [[ $dirname =~ ^git:.*\.git$ ]]; then
        dirname=$(echo $dirname | sed s/.git$//)
    fi

    cd $dirname
        git remote rm origin
        git filter-branch --tree-filter \
            "(mkdir -p $dirname; find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name . ! -name .git ! -name $dirname -exec mv {} $dirname/ \;)"
        cd ..

    cd new-repo
        git pull --no-commit ../$dirname
        [ $x -gt 0 ] && git commit -m "merge made by $me"
        cd ..

    x=$(( x + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! However, I had to change line 22 to: `if [[ $dirname =~ ^.*\.git$ ]]; then`

Comment: ^.*blarg$ is wastefully greedy RE.  Better to say .blarg$ and skip the front anchor.

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to simply glue two repositories together, submodules and subtree merges are the wrong tool to use because they don't preserve all of the file history (as people have noted on other answers). See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14470212/1174561) for the simple and correct way to do this.

Comment: Your solution works well only for new repository, but how about to merge repo in another one with file conflicts?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar challenge, but in my case, we had developed one version of the codebase in repo A, then cloned that into a new repo, repo B, for the new version of the product. After fixing some bugs in repo A, we needed to FI the changes into repo B. Ended up doing the following:

1. Adding a remote to repo B that pointed to repo A (git remote add...)
2. Pulling the current branch (we were not using master for bug fixes) (git pull remoteForRepoA bugFixBranch)
3. Pushing merges to github

Worked a treat :)

Answer (score 6):

Merging 2 repos

```
git clone ssh://<project-repo> project1
cd project1
git remote add -f project2 project2
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories project2/master
git remote rm project2

delete the ref to avoid errors
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/project2/master
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to @Smar but uses file system paths, set in PRIMARY and SECONDARY:

```
PRIMARY=~/Code/project1
SECONDARY=~/Code/project2
cd $PRIMARY
git remote add test $SECONDARY && git fetch test
git merge test/master
```

Then you manually merge.

(adapted from [post by Anar Manafov](http://eatmyrandom.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-merge-two-independent-git.html))

Answer (score 4):

When you want to merge three or more projects in a **single** commit, do the steps as described in the other answers (`remote add -f`, `merge`). Then, (soft) reset the index to old head (where no merge happened). Add all files (`git add -A`) and commit them (message "Merging projects A, B, C, and D into one project). This is now the commit-id of master.

Now, create `.git/info/grafts` with following content:

```
<commit-id of master> <list of commit ids of all parents>
```

Run `git filter-branch -- head^..head head^2..head head^3..head`. If you have more than three branches, just add as much `head^n..head` as you have branches. To update tags, append `--tag-name-filter cat`. Do not always add that, because this might cause a rewrite of some commits. For details see [man page of filter-branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html), search for "grafts".

Now, your last commit has the right parents associated.

Comment: Wait, why would you want to merge three projects in a single commit?

Comment: I started with repository, repository-client, and modeler as separate git projects. This was difficult for the co-workers, so I joined them in a single git project. To be able that the "root" of the new project originates from three other projects, I wanted to have *single* merge commit.

Answer (score 4):

To merge a A within B:

1) In the project A

```
git fast-export --all --date-order > /tmp/ProjectAExport
```

2) In the project B

```
git checkout -b projectA
git fast-import --force < /tmp/ProjectAExport
```

In this branch do all operations you need to do and commit them.

C) Then back to the master and a classical merge between the two branches:

```
git checkout master
git merge projectA
```

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/hraban/tomono as another mention of a script-based solution.

I am not the author but used it and it does the job.

One positive aspect is that you get all the branches and all the history into the final repo. For my repos (no duplicate folders in repos - actually, they came out of tfs2git migration) there were no conflicts and everything ran automated.

It is mainly used (see name) to create monorepos.

For Windows users: git bash can execute the .sh file. It comes with the standard git installation.

Comment: +1 from me . And you can merge B into your existing repo A as a subdirectory, by setting A as the "existing monorepo". See https://github.com/hraban/tomono#continue-existing-migration . TLDR : `MONOREPO_NAME=A tomono --continue <<<"git@github.com:user/B.git B"`

Answer (score 4):

There is a Copybara tool used by Google for more complex use cases - https://github.com/google/copybara

Answer (score 3):

I merge projects slightly manually, which allows me to avoid needing to deal with merge conflicts.

first, copy in the files from the other project however you want them.

```
cp -R myotherproject newdirectory
git add newdirectory
```

next pull in the history

```
git fetch path_or_url_to_other_repo
```

tell git to merge in the history of last fetched thing

```
echo 'FETCH_HEAD' > .git/MERGE_HEAD
```

now commit however you normally would commit

```
git commit
```

Comment: This was the only solution that made any sense, and did exactly what I wanted and expected.

Answer (score 3):

I had to solve it as follows today:
Project A was in bitbucket and Project B was in code commit .. both are the same projects but had to merge changes from A to B. (The trick is to create the same name branch in Project A, same as in Project B)

- git checkout Project A
- git remote remove origin
- git remote add origin Project B
- git checkout branch
- git add *
- git commit -m "we have moved the code"
- git push

Answer (score 2):

This function will clone remote repo into local repo dir, after merging all commits will be saved, `git log` will be show the original commits and proper paths:

```
function git-add-repo
{
    repo="$1"
    dir="$(echo "$2" | sed 's/\/$//')"
    path="$(pwd)"

    tmp="$(mktemp -d)"
    remote="$(echo "$tmp" | sed 's/\///g'| sed 's/\./_/g')"

    git clone "$repo" "$tmp"
    cd "$tmp"

    git filter-branch --index-filter '
        git ls-files -s |
        sed "s,\t,&'"$dir"'/," |
        GIT_INDEX_FILE="$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" git update-index --index-info &&
        mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
    ' HEAD

    cd "$path"
    git remote add -f "$remote" "file://$tmp/.git"
    git pull "$remote/master"
    git merge --allow-unrelated-histories -m "Merge repo $repo into master" --edit "$remote/master"
    git remote remove "$remote"
    rm -rf "$tmp"
}
```

How to use:

```
cd current/package
git-add-repo https://github.com/example/example dir/to/save
```

If make a little changes you can even move files/dirs of merged repo into different paths, for example:

```
repo="https://github.com/example/example"
path="$(pwd)"

tmp="$(mktemp -d)"
remote="$(echo "$tmp" | sed 's/\///g' | sed 's/\./_/g')"

git clone "$repo" "$tmp"
cd "$tmp"

GIT_ADD_STORED=""

function git-mv-store
{
    from="$(echo "$1" | sed 's/\./\\./')"
    to="$(echo "$2" | sed 's/\./\\./')"

    GIT_ADD_STORED+='s,\t'"$from"',\t'"$to"',;'
}

# NOTICE! This paths used for example! Use yours instead!
git-mv-store 'public/index.php' 'public/admin.php'
git-mv-store 'public/data' 'public/x/_data'
git-mv-store 'public/.htaccess' '.htaccess'
git-mv-store 'core/config' 'config/config'
git-mv-store 'core/defines.php' 'defines/defines.php'
git-mv-store 'README.md' 'doc/README.md'
git-mv-store '.gitignore' 'unneeded/.gitignore'

git filter-branch --index-filter '
    git ls-files -s |
    sed "'"$GIT_ADD_STORED"'" |
    GIT_INDEX_FILE="$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" git update-index --index-info &&
    mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
' HEAD

GIT_ADD_STORED=""

cd "$path"
git remote add -f "$remote" "file://$tmp/.git"
git pull "$remote/master"
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories -m "Merge repo $repo into master" --edit "$remote/master"
git remote remove "$remote"
rm -rf "$tmp"
```

**Notices**
Paths replaces via `sed`, so make sure it moved in proper paths after merging.
The `--allow-unrelated-histories` parameter only exists since git >= 2.9.

Answer (score 1):

Given command is the best possible solution I suggest.

```
git subtree add --prefix=MY_PROJECT git://github.com/project/my_project.git master
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the answers using `remote add` -> `fetch` -> `merge` strategy: if you want to preserve tags from the other repository but don't want to spill them all into a common namespace (and possibly get collisions) you might want to change the fetch command a little bit:

```
git fetch --no-tags other_repo
git fetch --no-tags other_repo 'refs/tags/*:refs/tags/other_repo/*'
```

First command fetches all the branches as usual, but omits tags attached to commits, the second one also omits the usual tag fetching mechanism (`git help fetch` for more), and fetches all the tags mapping them from `X` to `other_repo/X` using git's refspec functionality.

References (branches, tags) are just files in git, and you can use directories for namespacing. The two commands above will preserve tags from the first repository as-is, and the ones from the other one will be prefixed with `other_repo/`

After the operation it's best to remove the other remote, so you don't accidentally fetch the tags the normal way and make a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to move a small project to a subdirectory of a larger one.  Since my small project did not have many commits, I used `git format-patch --output-directory /path/to/patch-dir`.  Then on the larger project, I used `git am --directory=dir/in/project /path/to/patch-dir/*`.

This feels *way* less scary and way more cleaner than a filter-branch.  Granted, it may not be applicable to all cases.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: this solution may push uneeded LFS binaries (that are not used by the merge's ancestor commits), so you might want to improve this solution.**

To complete the good [answer by Andresch Serj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548919/4669135) in the case the `project-a` uses `Git LFS` in order to be able to push I had to first do:

```
cd /path/to/project-a
git lfs fetch --all # some old LFS objects might only be on the server of project-a and not in your clone of project-a

# possible alternative to the following two commands (untested): do a git lfs fetch from path/to/project-b
git remote add project-b-origin url-to-project-b-server
git lfs push --all project-b-origin
```

In my case this fixed the errors I got when attempting to `git push` the merge result in project-a clone directory:

```
remote: GitLab: LFS objects are missing. Ensure LFS is properly set up or try a manual "git lfs push --all".
```

and

```
Unable to find source for object <hash> (try running `git lfs fetch --all`)
Git LFS upload failed:
    (missing) <path> (<hash>)
```