# error combining git repositories into subdirs

Tags: git, history

I have looked at several threads addressing this.

[Combining multiple git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories)

[Combining multiple git repositories having a space in their name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369591/combining-multiple-git-repositories-having-a-space-in-their-name)

I also looked at the git filter-branch manpage.

---

update

I have changed to a 2 script system:

```
#!/bin/bash
git filter-branch --index-filter '~/doit.sh' HEAD
```

and doit.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
git ls-files -s | \ 
    sed "s-\t-&data/perl_modules/-" | \ 
    GIT_INDEX_FILE="$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" git update-index --index-info && \
    mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
```

This avoids the previous error, but now gets this (replaced path with [...]):

```
Rewrite c35e4ef0626fb2045f57fa5b605e7663b8d06196 (1/10977)mv: cannot stat `[...]/.git-rewrite/t/../index.new': No such file or directory
index filter failed: ~/doit.sh
```

When I run the

```
ls-files- s | sed ... | git update-index ...
```

I get the index file it should generate. As well when I change the doit.sh file to output the result of sed instead of piping it to git update-index it appears to produce the proper output... it seems git update-index is simply not creating the file when run under --index-filter....

---

Update again:

When I change

mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"

to

mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE" || true

It fails the first mv, but all the others (so far) are working.

---

All of this culminated in this script:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
    'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&data/perl_modules/-" |
            GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
                    git update-index --index-info &&
     mv $GIT_INDEX_FILE.new $GIT_INDEX_FILE' HEAD
```

Theoretically this script should take all the files in the repository, shove them into data/perl_modules/, and rewrite history so that it appears the files have always been in that directory.

However I get this error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'ls-files': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

Not sure how to proceed, I don't understand the script well enough to debug it, and it is taken directly from the git filter-branch manpage.

I have tried this both before and after manually moving the files to the subdir in case it required they be moved, or required they not be moved.

Comment: Brett Randall has now submitted a patch to the Git mailing list which can be inspected at http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/270407

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There were a couple problems.

**1) git filter-branch --index filter was not using the '...' properly.**

I am not sure why this is, a bug with git-filter, an environment problem? who knows. But I was able to fix it by moving everything out of the '...' and putting it into a script file. I then called the script inside the ''

```
git filter-branch --index-filter '~/doit.sh' HEAD
```

And doit.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

git ls-files -s | \ 
    sed "s-\t-&data/perl_modules/-" | \ 
    GIT_INDEX_FILE="$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" git update-index --index-info

mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE" || true
```

**2) The first commit was empty, so there was no index.new to mv**

This git repo was imported from svn using git-svn. As such the first commit was completely empty simply saying initial svn repo initialization. As such there were no files moved, and no index.new to move. This was solved by adding || true to the mv command. Note however that if more than one mv command fails you have other problems.

Comment: if the first commit is the one with issues it would be better (in my opinion) to replace "HEAD", by "SHA2 of second commit..HEAD".

Comment: @rufo As I have commented elsewhere, it painfully turns out that replacing HEAD with REV2..HEAD is _not_ a general solution.

Comment: Solution for me was to add `if [ -f "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" ]; then mv...EX_FILE"; fi` -- for some reason there was a legitimate commit in svn (on a build.info file) that did not make it into git after the git svn clone.  And for whatever reason removing empty commits did not pick this one up.

Comment: @Ryan Can you tell me where exactly you put that? I have exactly the same problem, it's frustrating.

Comment: Like this:  `if [ -f "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" ]; then mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"; fi`

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have \ missing in some of the multiline breaks.

Comment: Tried turning it all into one line to avoid need for \, same problem.

Comment: how about other \ symbols. Did you try and escape them? Also, * may be causing issues. Start with a simpler script than what you have and add complexity incrementally (use of \ and *).

Comment: That is not the issue, see my latest update. I replaced everything in the single quotes with a call to script containing what they used to have. Now I get a different error.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't had issues with filter-branch before like this. Have you checked with the guys on the #git irc channel? I usually get great help there. Meanwhile, I'll try to recreate this on my own.

Comment: the #git channel on freenode had little interest in my question. Maybe I asked at a bad time?

Comment: This is a repo that was imported from svn if that makes a difference.

Comment: Oh, also I am using zsh, maybe the interpolation is having an effect?

Comment: yes, the shell can have a different interpretation and escaping. Try omitting the script file. Just concentrate on update index not working. Do something dead simple that exercises that..

Comment: I have actually completely solved my problem at this point. I simply cannto post the answer for another several hours due to my reputation. I have a very pretty and nice detailed explanation of all problems and solutions, and will post them when I am allowed.