# Prune empty merge commits from history in Git repository

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have cleaned up our Git repository quite a bit, we need to remove big parts from the history. I do this using:

```bash
git filter-branch --prune-empty --tree-filter 'rm -rf some_stuff'
```

The `--prune-empty` flag will remove commits that are left empty after the process, except commits with multiple parents (merge commits). Even if the branch being merged in contains absolutely nothing, and the merge adds nothing to the tree.

How do I also prune these empty merge commits from the history?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a very cute little wrapper script around filter-branch here:

https://github.com/pflanze/chj-bin/blob/master/cj-git-filter-branch

Preconds and background here:

http://lists.q42.co.uk/pipermail/git-announce/2011-September/000486.html

Comment: It does not work. From `man git filter-branch`: "You can also use the git_commit_non_empty_tree "$@" instead of git commit-tree "$@" if you don’t wish to keep commits with a single parent and that makes no change to the tree." But merge commits have multiple parents. So it does the same as the `--prune-empty` flag. I tried it, and it does not prune the empty merge commits. :/

Comment: Aah ok, damn. More research needed then. Brb.

Comment: Check out that wrapper script.

Comment: I am unable to get the perl script to work, I am getting a `Can't locate Chj/xperlfunc.pm in @INC ...` error. And if I google xperlfunc I don't find anything useful. Did you have success using this script?

Comment: Sorry forgot a link http://lists.q42.co.uk/pipermail/git-announce/2011-September/000486.html

Comment: Hi, yes, now it works beautifully. You should edit your answer with the information in the comments, and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 51):

This is **superior to the rebase solution** because it **preserves committer info, committer dates, and non-empty merges** of the original history.

```sh
git filter-branch --prune-empty --parent-filter \
    'sed "s/-p //g" | xargs -r git show-branch --independent | sed "s/\</-p /g"'
```

This is inspired by the same [thread on the kernel mailing list](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Removing-useless-merge-commit-with-quot-filter-branch-quot-td7356544.html) than Lucas' solution. However it does not require Ruby and is a one-liner. It *does* require GNU versions of `xargs` and `sed` though.

Comment: Simplest solution for me, because no external scripts are needed.

Comment: On OSX `sed "s/-p //g" | xargs git show-branch --independent | sed "s/^/-p /g" | tr "\n" " "` appears to work for me

Comment: Does not remove merge commits from bottom tree i.e. merge of two empty commits (each without ancestor)

Comment: Another macOS option: `brew install gnu-sed findutils` so you can replace sed with gsed and xargs with gxargs fpr GNU goodness.

Answer (score 11):

I needed to do this after running `filter-branch` on a copy of [ssokolow/profile](https://github.com/ssokolow/profile) to separate out [ssokolow/lap](https://github.com/ssokolow/lap).

This did a decent job as an automatic "collapse away anything left vestigial by `--prune-empty`" command:

```
git rebase --root HEAD
```

(I needed the `--root` so it would replace the now-empty initial commit with the oldest one that still had content.)

Comment: Useful, though overkill in some situations.  It's worth noting that this approach flattens *all* merges, not just the empty ones.

Comment: Note also that this resets GIT_COMMITTER_DATE as what git rebase does by default.

Comment: @ElanRuusamäe: Do you know of a way to avoid that (i.e. keep the original commiter info)?

Comment: @Thilo: Looking at the documentation for `git rebase` and `git am` (which git rebase delegates to), I think using `--committer-date-is-author-date` should work. I haven't tried yet myself, but I am about to.

Comment: This `git rebase` command is asking me to fix hundreds of "*error: could not apply*". Is there a way to skip them all?

Comment: You shouldn't be getting those errors. Something went horribly wrong.

Comment: "Could not apply" is a very common error in this scenario.   It just means that it encountered a merge commit with a change on both branches, so it cannot rebase into a linear history.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it worked for me: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Removing-useless-merge-commit-with-quot-filter-branch-quot-td7356544.html

```
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --parent-filter FULL_PATH_TO/rewrite_parent.rb master
```

`rewrite_parent.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby 
old_parents = gets.chomp.gsub('-p ', ' ') 

if old_parents.empty? then 
  new_parents = [] 
else 
  new_parents = `git show-branch --independent #{old_parents}`.split 
end 

puts new_parents.map{|p| '-p ' + p}.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`--prune-degenerate`](https://www.mankier.com/1/git-filter-repo#--prune-degenerate) option in `git-filter-repo` can be used for this:

> [Merge commits] can become degenerate with the pruning of other commits (having fewer than two parents, having one commit serve as both parents, or having one parent as the ancestor of the other.) If such merge commits have no file changes, they [will be] pruned.

```bash
git filter-repo --prune-degenerate always
```

Keep in mind that the above command will apply to the whole repo by default. You can specify [`--refs`](https://www.mankier.com/1/git-filter-repo#Examples-Partial_history_rewrites) if you want to limit the impact.

Answer (score 0):

So my solution is moving everything to sub-dir (historically) and then `--subdirectory-filter`

First step [error combining git repositories into subdirs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798142/error-combining-git-repositories-into-subdirs/7802021#7802021)

I modified a bit the sh file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t-&temp_dir/-" | GIT_INDEX_FILE="$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" git update-index --index-info

mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE" || true
```

run

```bash
git filter-branch --index-filter '~/doit.sh' HEAD
```

second step

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter temp_dir --prune-empty
```

and push it.