# The --prune-empty switch for git filter-branch does not prune empty commit at beginning of branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have a single commit at the start of my master branch containing a `.gitignore` file.

When I run

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'git rm .gitignore' --prune-empty
```

The new tree still contains that node, although empty (the .gitignore file has been removed), so half of the job has been done.

Why did not `--prune-empty` prune the empty commit? Or did I misunderstand that switch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2016: The `prune-empty` option of [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) does mention:

> this switch only applies for commits that have one and only one parent

If your modified commit was "at the beginning of the `master` branch", it has 0 parent.
That particular commit, even empty, will not be pruned.

---

If your modified commit was "at the beginning of a branch",

```
beginning of a branch b
     |
     v
--x--Y--z--z
      \
       b--b
```

[it should be pruned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23186268/6309) only if that empty commit is identical to the previous commit.

As [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) [mentions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28313729/6309):*

> **an "empty commit" is really one that has the same tree as the previous commit**: it's not that it has no files at all, it's that it has all the same files, with the same modes, and the same contents, as its parent commit.
> This is because git stores complete snapshots for each commit, not differences from one commit to the next.

As the doc says:

> Some kind of filters will generate empty commits, that **left the tree untouched**.

So a commit with "0 files" is *not* an "empty commit" from the point of view of filter-branch, unless the parent commit *also* has "0 files" (i.e. the same [empty "semi-secret" tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766506/6309))

---

Note: this has changed with Git 2.13 (Q2 2017): "[`git filter-branch --prune-empty`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/529635738683b4570b1cee894fa53bce66254e8b/Documentation/git-filter-branch.txt#L169)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#Documentation/git-filter-branch.txt---prune-empty))</sup> drops a single-parent commit that becomes a no-op, but did not drop a root commit whose tree is empty.

See [commit 32da746](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32da7467ebc099e6032590773827884b704980cf), [commit a582a82](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a582a82d2444b627260a764c17d3137d9d255531), [commit 4dacc8f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4dacc8f11d4acfb43d76e2a1abc2d2a57d5a2691), [commit 377a354](https://github.com/git/git/commit/377a3543898815dda82e0b33de152958318e7bff) (23 Feb 2017) by [Devin J. Pohly (`djpohly`)](https://github.com/djpohly).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5296357](https://github.com/git/git/commit/529635738683b4570b1cee894fa53bce66254e8b), 14 Mar 2017)</sup>

> ### [`filter-branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a582a82d2444b627260a764c17d3137d9d255531): fix --prune-empty on parentless commits
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Devin J. Pohly</sup>

> Previously, the `git_commit_non_empty_tree` function would always pass any commit with no parents to `git-commit-tree`, regardless of whether the tree was nonempty.
> The new commit would then be recorded in the filter-branch revision map, and subsequent commits which leave the tree untouched would be correctly filtered.
>
> With this change, parentless commits with an empty tree are correctly pruned, and an empty file is recorded in the revision map, signifying that it was rewritten to "no commits."  This works naturally with the parent mapping for subsequent commits.

`git filter-branch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a582a82d2444b627260a764c17d3137d9d255531/Documentation/git-filter-branch.txt#L170-L175):

> Some filters will generate empty commits that leave the tree untouched.
> This option instructs git-filter-branch to remove such commits if they
> have exactly one or zero non-pruned parents; merge commits will
> therefore remain intact.  This option cannot be used together with
> `--commit-filter`, though the same effect can be achieved by using the
> provided `git_commit_non_empty_tree` function in a commit filter.

Comment: Title changed, added ...at beginning of branch.

Comment: @AndersLindén I have edited the answer to address the case "beginning of a branch", which led me to revisit the notion of "empty commit"

Comment: It seems like the commit that only had the .gitignore file before the git filter-branch is now empty in all senses. But as you pointed out "this switch only applies for commits that have one and only one parent". Shouldnt the function be changed to "this switch only applies for commits that have one parent or is the initial commit"?

Comment: @AndersLindén since the initial commit has 0 parent, it would not be pruned. That is because of the definition of "empty commit" in Git, which actually is a "non-modified tree compared to the parent commit".

Comment: Yes, but the rephrasing proposal would include the initial commit.

Comment: @AndersLindén no, because an  "empty commit" in Git, which actually is a "non-modified tree compared to the parent commit". Hence, there cannot be an "empty commit" for an initial commit.

Comment: I think an imaginary commit (before the initial commit) should be added to the git vocabulary. If you check out that commit, it will be like checking out orphan, but you do not have to create a new branch. Then initial commit/s could be seen as empty as well.

Comment: Has this behavior changed in newer git versions? With version 2.25, I ran a `filter-branch --index-filter` removing some files, and that empty initial commit is gone. I noticed because the same operation 3 years ago had left it. The manpage now says “remove such commits if they have exactly one or zero non-pruned parents”.

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong Yes, It has changed with Git 2.13 (Q2 2017). I have edited the answer to document that.