# List all git commits that have no files changed

Tags: git

I'm working with an open source repository that seems to have been copied over from either a combined git repo or some other kind of VCS. There are an enormous amount of commits in the repo, most of them with zero files changed:

[image: Almost 40 thousand commits]

[image: Most of them have changed zero files]

What would be the best way to list all the commits with no files changed, count them, and potentially remove them from the local git repo?

Edit: I'm specifically looking for a way to assess the extent of the issue before running a time consuming, destructive command like `filter-branch` as referenced in [Remove empty commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313664/remove-empty-commits-in-git)

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/28313729/3124288 is what you're looking for?

Comment: Awesome, this is perfect for pruning the empties, thanks.

Comment: @Whymarrh I think there's a small difference here - I was specifically interested in seeing the extent of the problem *before* using a destructive command like `filter-branch`, if you take a look at my answer.

Comment: Although I'm also happy to add some of these as an additional answer there if it seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the keyword I was missing in Google was "empty" (was searching for "remove commits with no files changes", etc)

List commits that have **no** changes (**empty** commits):

```
git rev-list HEAD | while read commitHash; do
    if [ $(git diff-tree --name-status --no-commit-id $commitHash | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $commitHash
    fi;
done
```

List commits that **have** changes, and files changed (**non** empty commits):

```
git rev-list HEAD | while read commitHash; do
    git diff-tree --name-status $commitHash
done
```

Count **empty** commits

```
git rev-list HEAD | while read commitHash; do
    if [ $(git diff-tree --name-status --no-commit-id $commitHash | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
        echo '1'
    fi;
done | wc -l
```

Count **non empty** commits

```
git rev-list HEAD | while read commitHash; do
    if [ $(git diff-tree --name-status --no-commit-id $commitHash | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then
        echo '1'
    fi;
done | wc -l
```

And finally, as per [@JKillian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3124288/jkillian)'s suggestion, remove all empty commits from the repo using `git filter-branch`:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --commit-filter 'git_commit_non_empty_tree "$@"' -- --all
```

Documentation on `filter-branch`, specifically `--commit-filter`:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#git-filter-branch---commit-filterltcommandgt

Comment: observe that these show empty commits relevant to the position of `HEAD`. Ie. if a root commit was checked out you'd get different results than if your on `main/master`