# Remove useless merges (those without any 'non-mainline' commits) after filter-branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-history-graph

I've performed a `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatched badfiles/ badfiles2/' --prune-empty` (per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository#comment1286334_955793)) to remove a bunch of files in preparation for moving the remaining files to another repository. `--prune-empty` gets rid of any resulting empty-commits, but it doesn't act on merges, which makes sense.

Now the history for this particular repo looks pretty ugly with a bunch of merges that don't actually add anything and some merges that are just merges of other merges that didn't actually add any changes (in the rewritten history; they may have been 'useful' before the filter-branch).

Consider this annotated snippet (generated with `git log --graph --oneline --shortstat`):

```
*   575e3b5 Merge pull request #68 from chris/feature # KEEP THIS MERGE!
|\  
| * 5dbc3f1 Actual feature changes
| |  2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
| * 35abc98 Cleanup/prep
|/  
|    2 files changed, 22 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)
*   c3b3d86 Merge pull request #46 from org/topic_branch-mods # USELESS-C
|\  
* \   892de05 Merge pull request #47 from org/topic_branch # USELESS-B
|\ \  
| |/  
|/|   
| *   e738d4b Merge branch 'master' into topic_branch # USELESS-A
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | 4182dac CommitMsg #40 #SQUASHED-PR
| |  2 files changed, 15 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
* | 3b42762 CommitMsg
|/  
|    2 files changed, 29 insertions(+), 14 deletions(-)
* c4e62ba CommitMsg
|  2 files changed, 39 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)
* c2bb13f CommitMsg
   4 files changed, 241 insertions(+)
```

I'd like to shorten this to (obviously with different id's as appropriate):

```
*   575e3b5 Merge pull request #68 from chris/feature # KEEP THIS MERGE!
|\  
| * 5dbc3f1 Actual feature changes
| |  2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
| * 35abc98 Cleanup/prep
|/  
|    2 files changed, 22 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-) 
* 4182dac CommitMsg #40 #SQUASHED-PR
|  2 files changed, 15 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
* 3b42762 CommitMsg
|  2 files changed, 29 insertions(+), 14 deletions(-)
* c4e62ba CommitMsg
|  2 files changed, 39 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)
* c2bb13f CommitMsg
   4 files changed, 241 insertions(+)
```

So I'd like to get rid of the 'USELESS' merges, which are all '*empty*' merges (no merge changes), but I'd like to preserve the history/grouping associated with the *also-'empty'* KEEP merge at the top, which groups those commits together into one 'changeset'.

Or looking at another example in the traditional simplified-sideways-history:

```
A -- B -- C -- D   ==>  A -- B --- D'
 \----\--/   /                \-E-/
       \----E
```

I have tried solutions to remove 'empty' merges (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38420284/880767)), but those remove *all* empty merges, and I want to keep the 'useful' empty merges as displayed in the examples...

As far as I can tell, **the 'useless' empty merges don't contain any commits that aren't all the way to the left/top in the history. Is there a way to filter those out cleanly?** I guess I don't really even know how to describe/define those...

Note that the given example was intentionally simple. For what it's worth, later in the history this repo looks like this, all of which I'd like to prune:

```
*   3d37e42 Merge pull request #239 from jim/topic-dev
|\  
| *   05eaf9e Merge pull request #7 from org/master
| |\  
| |/  
|/|  
* |   1576482 Merge pull request #193 from john/master
|\ \  
| * \   187100e Merge branch 'master' of github.com:org/repo into master
| |\ \  
| * \ \   067cc55 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:org/repo into master
| |\ \ \  
| * \ \ \   a69e3d2 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:org/repo into master
| |\ \ \ \  
| | |/ / /  
* | | | |   0ce6813 Merge pull request #212 from jim/feature
|\ \ \ \ \  
| | |_|_|/  
| |/| | |   
| * | | |   0f5352e Merge pull request #5 from org/master
| |\ \ \ \  
| |/ / / /
```

Comment: have you considered using git rebase to squash commits?

Comment: I did consider rebase, but was unaware of the `-r | --rebase-merges` option, which can enable one to strip out commits while preserving some of the structure. _However_, rebase modifies the 'committer' and commit-date, which I'd like to preserve from the originals - not to fool anyone, but to preserve the history of who actually merged a particular PR and when. It also becomes a very manual process at that point, picking each merge to keep/drop. But if one really really wants to clean up the history and is ok with modifying the commit details, that's a decent suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I don't think this is perfect, but it does solve the problem in this particular case; there are cases where it doesn't *quite* clean up as much as it perhaps could, but it's a step if anyone is interested:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
if ! git rev-parse --verify "$GIT_COMMIT^2" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ||
  [ "$(git log --no-merges "$GIT_COMMIT^2" "^$GIT_COMMIT^1" --oneline | wc -l)" -gt 0 ];
then
  #echo take $GIT_COMMIT >&2
  # Pick one:
  git_commit_non_empty_tree "$@" # Drop empty commits
  #git commit-tree "$@" # Keep empty commits
else
  #echo "breakup $GIT_COMMIT ($*)" >&2
  skip_commit "$1" "$2" "$3" # (quietly) only keep the first parent
fi' -f HEAD
```

If 1) the commit doesn't have a second parent (`git rev-parse` returns an error if the referenced commit (`$GIT_COMMIT^2`) doesn't exist) OR 2) the second parent (`$GIT_COMMIT^2`) contains commits that the first parent (`$GIT_COMMIT^1`) does not (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710894/using-git-show-all-commits-that-are-in-one-branch-but-not-the-others)), the commit is kept (if it is not-empty; use `git commit-tree` if you want to keep empties); *if the second parent exists and doesn't add anything useful*, we skip the commit, and *intentionally* only pass the first parent-I'm not sure this is 'legit', but it drops the second parent from the history, and it worked in my case... (see caveats below)

From the bottom-up:

```
*   575e3b5 Merge pull request #68 from chris/feature # KEEP THIS MERGE!
|\  
| * 5dbc3f1 Actual feature changes
| |  2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
| * 35abc98 Cleanup/prep
|/  
|    2 files changed, 22 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)
*   c3b3d86 Merge pull request #46 from org/topic_branch-mods # USELESS-C
|\  
* \   892de05 Merge pull request #47 from org/topic_branch # USELESS-B
|\ \  
| |/  
|/|   
| *   e738d4b Merge branch 'master' into topic_branch # USELESS-A
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | 4182dac CommitMsg #40 #SQUASHED-PR
| |  2 files changed, 15 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
* | 3b42762 CommitMsg
|/  
|    2 files changed, 29 insertions(+), 14 deletions(-)
* c4e62ba CommitMsg
|  2 files changed, 39 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)
* c2bb13f CommitMsg
   4 files changed, 241 insertions(+)
```

It kept everything through `SQUASHED-PR` (note that commit id `4182dac` and parents are retained as their history didn't change). It decided `USELESS-A` should stick around b/c it's second parent (`4182dac`) contains commits its first parent (`c4e62ba`) did *not* contain, **but** then it looked at `USELESS-B`, whose second parent (*including* `USELESS-A`) *doesn't* add anything useful, so it dropped it (again, including `USELESS-A`). Then `USELESS-C` was just useless, so it got dropped, and `KEEP` had 'something useful' in the second parent, so it was retained. So you end with:

```
*   63b4d39 Merge pull request #68 from chris/feature # KEEP THIS MERGE!
|\  
| * 9a5570d Actual feature changes
| |  2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
| * a251317 Cleanup/prep
|/  
|    2 files changed, 22 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-) 
* 4182dac CommitMsg #40 #SQUASHED-PR
|  2 files changed, 15 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
* 3b42762 CommitMsg
|  2 files changed, 29 insertions(+), 14 deletions(-)
* c4e62ba CommitMsg
|  2 files changed, 39 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)
* c2bb13f CommitMsg
   4 files changed, 241 insertions(+)
```

## Important Caveats

- This only works for simple histories where there are only ever two branches as we're *explicitly* passing `"$1" "$2" "$3"` in this case leaving off `"$4" "$5"`, which would otherwise be included in `"$@"`. If you have multiple parents (or rather if your *commit* has multiple parents), you'll have to adjust this to account for that; shouldn't be too hard, but I'm not fixing it right now for a hypothetical - you may want to choose specific parents to drop, idk.
- If there were a 'useful' commit after `USELESS-A` before it got merged to `USELESS-B` (which arguably wouldn't be useless then), `USELESS-A` will *not* get pruned/dropped, so you'll still have some ugliness perhaps.
- There are likely other scenarios where this doesn't work or could be improved. Please add suggestions in the comments (as usual) if you find any!

Answer (score 1):

This is the heart of the problem:

> I guess I don't really even know how to describe/define those...

Git is, at its heart, a graph-manipulation program, designed to build DAGs (Directed Acyclic Graphs) where each node in the graph is a commit.  The fact that each commit carries a source snapshot as a sort of data payload is irrelevant to this process.  (It's of course highly relevant to Git eventually being *useful*.)

You want to take the existing (post-filtering) DAG and build a different DAG.  You'll need to define an algorithm for transforming the unwanted DAG to the wanted DAG.  You don't necessarily have to use `git filter-branch` to achieve the transformation, but if you intend to do so, you'll have to further refine this transformation into an algorithm that works with "so-far" knowledge: it can see the current commit hash ID, of a commit that filter-branch is proposing to copy.  That's in `$GIT_COMMIT`.  It can read that commit (using Git plumbing commands), and it can find the mapping from other already-copied commits using the shell function `map`, as described in [the `git filter-branch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

I, too, don't know quite how to define "useful merge".  I think the most obvious algorithm, though, is one that is not (at least directly) suited to filter-branch: it's an iterative relaxation algorithm in which you start with the complete graph and repeatedly pluck out merge nodes, connecting their parents to their children, whenever those nodes are not useful.  (It's still up to you to define *not useful*.)  In the end, you have a list of nodes to keep and nodes to delete.  *That list is useful* to a filter you write for filter-branch: you would now run `git filter-branch` with a `--commit-filter` that either runs `git commit-tree` as usual, or the provided `skip_commit` function as described in the documentation.  The decision "keep" or "skip" is based on the list you generated with your relaxation algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, I get what you're saying. As I developed the question, I think the closest I got was 'useful merges contain commits that are not in the far-left of the graph, or merges thereof'; I guess you'd look for commits that are in the second parent that are not in the first? It looks like that would remove the 'useless' commits in my examples without removing the 'useful' one... which then I guess uses a --commit-filter and perhaps. Actually, I think something like `git log --no-merges HEAD^2 ^HEAD^1` will show if there are valid commits; now to make that a filter... which I'll look at tomorrow.

Comment: Actually, I think automating this may be impossible, or at least even more complicated than I anticipated (and I anticipated complicated), as USELESS-A actually has the 'mainline' coming in as the second parent (going out to the right and back in - an important distinction), so it would not be removed (ok, I can deal with that), and _skipping_ USELESS-B actually doesn't have the effect of removing the merge - just pushes it to the next child, which complicates things even further. I think you'd have to drop the parent, and not sure you can reliably do that with just 'so-far' knowledge...

Comment: That's why I suggested a relaxation algorithm. Technically I guess [stationary iterative algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method#Stationary_iterative_methods) is a better phrase (although this seems to be aimed more at equation solving, rather than graph simplification). Dijkstra's shortest-path algorithm uses relaxation and is, I think, where I got the idea.