# Why does git's cherry picking with more than one commit fail?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I try to merge two repos, yielding a flat (aka interleaved) history. I do this along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/a/14839653/188108, under "History rewrite:".

The two branches to merge are in "master" and "src/master".  Then, I write:

```
$ git checkout --orphan new-master
$ git cherry-pick 9d325d6d 3f4c52ba
error: a cherry-pick or revert is already in progress
hint: try "git cherry-pick (--continue | --quit | --abort)"
fatal: cherry-pick failed
$ git cherry-pick 9d325d6d && git cherry-pick 3f4c52ba
[new-master 10f0277] Initial revision.
 7 files changed, 194 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 __init__.py
 create mode 100644 manage.py
 create mode 100644 samples/__init__.py
 create mode 100644 samples/models.py
 create mode 100644 samples/views.py
 create mode 100644 settings.py
 create mode 100644 urls.py
[new-master 08e083c] Fixed field name in SixChambersLayer.  Added Sample.current_place.
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

So, why does the first cherry pick command fail, but the split command works?  I use git 1.9.1.

Comment: I have this same problem but with git 2.8.2.  I ended up using `echo sha1 sha1 sha1 | xargs -n1 git cherry-pick` to workaround this problem I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead:

```
git cherry-pick 9d325d6d^..3f4c52ba
```

As I mentioned in "[How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309)":

> In the "`cherry-pick A..B`" form, `A` should be older than `B`.
>   If they're the wrong order the command will silently fail.
>
> If you want to pick the range `B` through `D` (inclusive) that would be `B^..D`.

Comment: As explained in the linked SO answer, I have a list of SHA-1s that I need to cherry-pick in order to build a new branch from them.  In other words, they are only rarely consecutive.  `man 7 gitrevision` suggests that a mere list of commit IDs should work ...  Besides, I don't understand the  error message of `git cherry-pick`.

Comment: @bronger are you listing those commits in the right order (from the oldest to the newest)? Also on What OS are you? (to check if a more recent git would work better)

Comment: Yes, it is oldest to newest.  And it is Ubuntu 14.04 and its git.