# Creating a one GIT repository from a project with several repositories

Tags: git

Here is my situation. I have a project that looks (I have simplified) like this:

```
/file1.php
/file2.php
/folder1/
/folder2/folder3
```

Right now folder1 and folder2/fodler3 have existing GIT repositories. I would like to create a repository in / that would control all the project. However, I don't want to lose the history of the folder1 repository. Even though that I want to get rid of that repository, so that I just have one repository for the whole project.

What is the approach that I should take in order to mantain the history of folder1 repository and folder2/folder3 repository, but create a new repo in the root folder and get rid of those?

Answer (score 0):

Git 1.9.11 and later allows you to create subtrees using the `git subtree` command, but there are other options outlined the links below.

[How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

[Merge two Git repositories without breaking file history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history/14470212#14470212)