# migrate several github repos to one repo and still preserve the commit history

Tags: git, github

I have wrote some projects for crawl merchandise data from some e-commerce website. I organized
them into several github repos, which means the project that crawl the walmart stored in a github repo named walmart. So i have several repos like walmart, bestbuy now. I want to migrate  these repos into another one repo and still preserve the commit history. After google, i can't find a useful method to try. Is there a method to do that?

Comment: check [Merge two Git repositories without breaking file history](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14470212)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a repo which looks like

```
/rootOfTheRepo
  .git
  /walmart
  /bestbuy
```

what you could do is:

- Prepare the subrepos by moving the files where they should be in the final repo
- Go in one of the repo and fetch the commit from the other
- Merge the two `master` branch

In bash it would look like, from you local clones:

```
cd /path/to/walmartRepo
mkdir walmart
git mv file1 file2 dir1 dir2 walmart
git commit -am "Moved files"

cd /path/to/bestbuyRepo
mkdir bestbuy
git mv file1 file2 dir1 dir2 bestbuy
git commit -am "Moved files"

git remote add walmart /path/to/walmartRepo
git fetch --all
git merge walmart/master
```

Once you do this, your besbuy repo has been turned into a new global repo. You just need to create a corresponding repo on github, and push this new commit there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have follow [Merge two Git repositories without breaking file history](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14470212) to achive my purpose. The method you supply can hold the commit history?

Comment: Yes, the method I supply preserve the commit history