# Where exactly does the Remote Branch point to after fetching?

Tags: git, github

From the below code (source: [Merge two Git repositories without breaking file history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history)), I have trouble visualizing where exactly old_a/master and old_b/master point to at each step along the process.

```
# Assume the current directory is where we want the new repository to be created
# Create the new repository
git init

# Before we do a merge, we have to have an initial commit, so we'll make a dummy commit
dir > deleteme.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Initial dummy commit"

# Add a remote for and fetch the old repo
git remote add -f old_a <OldA repo URL>

# Merge the files from old_a/master into new/master
git merge old_a/master

# Clean up our dummy file because we don't need it any more
git rm .\deleteme.txt
git commit -m "Clean up initial file"

# Move the old_a repo files and folders into a subdirectory so they don't collide with the other repo coming later
mkdir old_a
dir -exclude old_a | %{git mv $_.Name old_a}

# Commit the move
git commit -m "Move old_a files into subdir"

# Do the same thing for old_b
git remote add -f old_b <OldB repo URL>
git merge old_b/master
mkdir old_b
dir –exclude old_a,old_b | %{git mv $_.Name old_b}
git commit -m "Move old_b files into subdir"
```

My questions:
1) Could someone draw (diagrams w/pointers) what happens to all the existing pointers at each step in the process?
2) What happens if you `git push old_a master` or `git push old_b master` after the steps above? (Do the repositories receive the entire new folder with both old_a + old_b stuff and why?)

Appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 0):

I won't draw a diagram, but `gitk` (or `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` if you prefer text-mode) can do that for you. By default, they show the history reachable from `HEAD`, add `--all` if you want to see all branches at the same time, or run `gitk old_a/master old_b/master` to view just the history of the two remote-tracking references you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't gonna draw for you. Use `gitk -a` to draw your history yourself.
2) I'm not sure if your `dir|%{}` commands are right, as I don't use windows cmds, but yes, if you push to old_a a/o old_b they will have the same layout as your local repository, that is

```
./old_a/AFILES
./old_b/BFILES
```

because git doesn't even care about files. Internally git just works with the contents, but you told git to mv all old_a files into a new directory ./old_a and same for old_b.

Actually git mv is a shell mv plus git rm oldpath and git add newpath.
these rm/add combinations will go to old_a and old_b when you push that commit.