# How to combine two git repos into one repo in parent folder?

Tags: git

I have two repos in the same parent folder that I want to combine in the parent folder, and if possible keep history without minimal diffs.

```
parent/
--code1/.git
--code2/.git
```

I would like:

```
parent/.git
--code1
--code2
```

Is it possible to do this and keep the history for both? Or at least code1 folder? Unfortunately there are some same-named branches in both repos. What would be ideal is to have both histories in .git by commit date, but I haven't found an easy solution (one complication is that git mv shows diffs from before/after commits with all files changed, but we can live with that).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two Git repositories without breaking file history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history)

Comment: Wolud `git subtree` or the subtree merge strategy help?

Answer (score 0):

You just want to merge two different repository (first and second) in a new one while keeping both git history:

Create a new git repository and make an initial commit:

```
mkdir newRepository
git init
touch .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit .gitignore -m 'init'
```

Fetch and merge the first:

```
git remote add first pathTo/first
git fetch first
git merge first/master
```

Fetch and merge the second:

```
git remote add second pathTo/second
git fetch second
git merge second/master
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to utilize the `git pull` method.

Do the following:

```
$ git init
$ git pull code1
$ git pull code2
```

This should create a merge.. Accept the merge (fix conflicts if any)..

To pull branches into the parent git repo, you can do the following:

```
$ git checkout -b branchName
$ git pull code1 branchName
```

---

EDIT: I had missed the part with you still wanting to keep the `code1` and `code2` folders. This is not really possible when you merge the two repositories, as it is doing what it says: merging them together, into the parent folder.. You would manually have to move source files into `code1` and `code2` afterwards and make further commits.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and came across this post. I eventually solved it by restructuring each repo before merging them together

repo1*content -> repo1\repo1newname*content
repo2*content -> repo2\repo2newname*content

each on their own branches cut off of HEAD/main

then I added both repos as remotes to the new repo and pulled from those branches

so it turned out as

newrepo
..\repo1newname
..\repo2newname

The restructuring added a renaming commit for each file, so the commit history of each file was retained, just with one extra commit for the renaming and another for the merging.

Hope this helps