# Combine two local git repos into new parent folder (new repo too)

Tags: git, github

The situation is as it follows:

- parent (.git, linked to remote github repo already)
- - child_0 (.git, local repo)
- - child_1 (.git, local repo)

I've been looking here but at least [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156343/how-to-combine-two-git-repos-into-one-repo-in-parent-folder) answers are vague in the proceeding.
My goal is to, if possible, just use the remote parent repo adding child_0 and child_1 commit history and manage them both from the parent.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75348228/7976758

Comment: Thank you, git add subtree worked perfectly! I think I missed that question since I used folder and they mention the word 'directory' instead.