# Merge two Git repositories and keep the master history

Tags: git

I need to **merge two Git repositories** into a brand new, third repository.
I followed the following instructions and they work, but the result is not what I expected. [Merge two Git repositories without breaking file history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Look at this:**

[image: Git Merge operation]

**The master is not aligned.**

- Is it possible to merge everything onto the same master?
- I would like to have a clean history on the master.

You are free to use my example repository's **on GitHub**:

- https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/RepoA
- https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/RepoB

This is my **merged result**.

- https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/Repo

**This is the situation that I would like to have:** (painted solution!!!)

[image: Painted solution!!]

**How I got to the the current situation:**

```
# Assume the current directory is where we want the new repository to be created
# Create the new repository
git init

# Before we do a merge, we have to have an initial commit, so we'll make a dummy commit
dir > Read.md
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"

# Add a remote for and fetch the old RepoA
git remote add -f RepoA https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/RepoA

# Merge the files from RepoA/master into new/master
git merge RepoA/master --allow-unrelated-histories

# Do the same thing for RepoB
git remote add -f RepoB https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/RepoB

# Merge the files from RepoB/master into new/master
git merge RepoB/master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

*All help is appreciated!*

**UPDATE: ANSWER**

The correct answer is to rebase, instead of merge.

- https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/RepoMerged

Code:

```
# Rebase the working branch (master) on top of repoB
git rebase RepoB/master

# Rebase teh working branch (master with RepoB) on top op repoA
git rebase RepoA/master
```

One problem remains. The 2nd repo loses the parent view. I posted a follow-up question for this: [Merge two Git repos and keep the history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292219/merge-two-git-repos-and-keep-the-history)

[image]

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you were expecting and how this is different?

Comment: You have everything on one master, I'm not sure what you mean by "aligned" - try removing the RepoA and RepoB remotes from your local and then see what the graph looks like.

Comment: I have added a 'painted solution'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy, instead of merging use [rebase](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/). Assuming you want to have `repoA/master` first just do (after fetching and adding remotes)

```
# starting on master
git rebase RepoB/master # place master on top of masterB
git rebase RepoA/master # place master (with masterB) on top of masterA
```

Note that rebases are potentially destructive and a bit unintuitive at first, so **I strongly recommend reading about them first** (SO documentation in the link above is a good place to start)

Comment: Thanks for the correct anwer. One minor problem: the rebase of RepoA makes me loose the merge history. See the image above (I added the current status in above). Is it possible to keep this?

Comment: @DimitriDewaele try the `--preserve-merges` option of `rebase`

Comment: As noted in @DimitriDewaele's follow-up question, `rebase` really isn't what you want to use for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42457384/54249