# Merge two Git repos with full history preserved / grafted (not rewritten)

Tags: git, merge, repository, rebase

I want to extend on another question I had: [Merge two Git repositories and keep the master history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161910/merge-two-git-repositories-and-keep-the-master-history)

I have succeeded in merging 2 different repo's into one repo. I needed a rebase to do this successfully. The master is correct, but **I also want to keep the merge history**. Is this possible?

I have 2 repositories:

- https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/RepoA
- https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/RepoB

[image: Repo A]

[image: Repo B]

This is the result after rebasing. **The times of the top repo are the rebase-time. The original date is lost!**

- https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/RepoMerged

[image: Rebase]

This is how I did it:

```
# Assume the current directory is where we want the new repository to be created
# Create the new repository
git init

# Before we do a merge, we have to have an initial commit, so we'll make a dummy commit
dir > Read.md
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"

# Add a remote for and fetch the old RepoA
git remote add -f RepoA https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/RepoA

# Do the same thing for RepoB
git remote add -f RepoB https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/RepoB

# Rebase the working branch (master) on top of repoB
git rebase RepoB/master

# Rebase the working branch (master with RepoB) on top op repoA
git rebase RepoA/master
```

**Is it possible to have something like this?** (*painted solution!!!*)

[image: Painted]

I would like to keep the original time + the merge history.

**UPDATE - ANSWER**

The answer that worked best for me, was working with graft points. But other answers are also very usable in other use cases. I have added my results on github, so everybody can evaluate.

**Answer 1: Best working in my case** The 'graft' did reveal the correct working answer for me.

[GitHub: RepoGraft](https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/RepoGraft)

[image]

**Answer 2** the "replace" option from "LeGEC" also gives good results for some use cases. One anomaly stayed for me:

[GitHub: RepoHistory](https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/RepoHistory)

[image]

**Answer 3: Worth adding** The answer from 'VonC'. I could not get the option '--preserve-merges working' in my case. This might work in other scenario's, but I did not test this furtner.

Comment: Do you want to keep repoA just to be able to inspect its history ? or will repoA be a live repositories, with new commits, pull requests etc ?

Comment: @LeGEC I would only like to inspect the history with branch history. New work wil happen on top of the resulting repo.

Comment: Dimitri, it's against SO policy for answers to be put into questions. Please move the answers that you added to the question into actual answers to (1) keep the question short and simple as possible and (2) allow people to vote on your answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you've discovered, `rebase` isn't the command you want to use to stitch histories together (because it actually rewrites history). Early Git had a feature (hack) designed specifically for what you're trying to do: [graft points](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint). Even better, since 1.6.5 you can use [`git replace --graft`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace#git-replace---graftltcommitgtltparentgt82308203) instead:

```
git checkout master
git replace --graft $(git log RepoB/master --format=%H | tail -1) HEAD
git replace --graft $(git log RepoA/master --format=%H | tail -1) RepoB/master
git reset --hard RepoA/master
```

(`git log RepoA/master --format=%H | tail -1` returns the initial commit from `RepoA`)

Technically you could skip the first `replace` if you don't actually have anything of value yet in `master`, yielding just history with RepoB + RepoA.

These commands create entries in `refs/replace/*` that can be pushed and pulled to share your revised history with others. Or, if you don't care about preserving the SHAs of RepoA/RepoB, you can make the replacements *permanent* by running `git filter-branch --all` to produce a "real" set of commits of the desired lineage.

Answer (score 2):

This answer suggests a different way to use `RepoB` as the active repo, and still have access to `RepoA` history :

use `git replace`

```
# start with a regular clone of the active repo :
$ git clone RepoB

# add repoA as a remote :
$ git remote add -f history https://github.com/DimitriDewaele/RepoA

# get hash of *initial* commit on repoB :
$ git log --oneline origin/master | tail -1
abcdef Initial commit

# get hash of last commit on repoA :
$ git log --oneline history/master | head -1
12345 Merge branch 'develop'

# use 'git replace' to tell git to stitch histories in the log :
$ git replace abcdef 12345
```

Note : this operation is done on your machine, not on the remote repositories, so should be repeated on all new clones.

*Variant* :

You may push `RepoA:master` to `RepoB` under a new name (e.g : `RepoB:history/master`), then you can use `git replace abcdef history/master`, on commits which are all stored in `RepoB`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options in git rebase that should be of interest in your case:

```
p
--preserve-merges
```

> Recreate merge commits instead of flattening the history by replaying commits a merge commit introduces.

```
--committer-date-is-author-date
```

(from [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am#git-am---committer-date-is-author-date))

> By default the command records the date from the e-mail message as the commit author date, and uses the time of commit creation as the committer date. This allows the user to lie about the committer date by using the same value as the author date.

Test if the second rebase doesn't yield a better result with:

```
git rebase -p --committer-date-is-author-date RepoA/master
```

Comment: Note that `--committer-date-is-author-date` still changes the committer to the rebaser, which may or may not be a problem. You really just don't want to use `rebase` for this.

Comment: @dahlbyk I know. I proposed that as a quick fix, but old grafting points mights do the job as well. +1

Comment: Indeed, good options to know about. Just not for this particular problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

An approach that worked for me and that doesn't involve using `git replace` is to push branches from one repository to the other, then usi `git rebase` to stitch them together.  For example, if I want to stitch branch `main` from repoA onto branch `main` in repoB:

```bash
# Push main branch from repoA to main_A branch on repoB
$ cd /path/to/repoA
$ git switch main
Switched to branch 'main'
$ git push /path/to/repoB main:main_A
git push /path/to/repoB main:main_A
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 228 bytes | 228.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To /path/to/repoB
 * [new branch]      main -> main_A

# Rebase main_A onto main. You need --root because branches are unrelated.
$ cd /path/to/repoB
$ git switch main_A
Switched to branch 'main_A'
$ git rebase --root --onto main
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/main_A.
$ git log
 ... (see if this looks right to you)

# Move the head of main to be the same as the rebased branch.
$ git switch main
Switched to branch 'main'
$ git merge --ff-only main_A  # Alternatively 'git reset --hard main_A'
Updating b9027b7..76f061e
Fast-forward
 ... etc.
```

Alternatively, you can rebase `main` onto `main_A` and avoid the last step; it all depends on which history you want to come first in the combined log.  To avoid merge conflicts during the rebase, it's a good idea to organize both
repos to minimize the files in common, i.e., by moving common files into
subdirectories before begining the process.  Even so, you might need
to spend some time handling the merge conflicts.  I found that the most common
conflicts were in `.gitignore`, and top-level makefiles or CMake files.