# Copy git history to a previously cloned repo

Tags: git, git-clone, git-history

I was wondering anyone has an idea how to copy an old git history to a new cloned repository which has been already worked on for some weeks.

I gathered it's possible when you clone it. also tried tools like this one
[enter link description here](https://github.com/pfrankov/git-copy-history)

But I'm over that point now and there are multiple new commits in the new repo.
So the annotations and date/time in the code only refers to the day I cloned it..

Any ideas how to copy the old git history to this new repo?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two Git repos and keep the history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292219/merge-two-git-repos-and-keep-the-history)

Comment: Check the question I suggested as duplicate. I would suggest my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42387360/86072