# Push existing repository into directory in another repository

Tags: git

First, sorry if the question was already answered, I didn't find an answer.

I have few git repositories and I want to put everything in a single repository.

I have that :

```
 ├── RepoOne
 │   └── someFiles
 │
 ├── RepoTwo
 │   └── someFiles
 │
 ├── RepoThree
 │   └── someFiles
```

And I want that :

```
 ├── BigRepo
 │   ├─── FolderOne
 │   │    ├── RepoOne
 │   │    └── RepoTwo
 │   │
 │   └─── FolderTwo
 │        └── RepoThree
```

But I want to keep the history of the old repo, their commits, etc..

How I can do that with git ? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories?

Comment: @Spads I tried all the answers and it seems that none do what I want..

Comment: So git merge --allow-unrelated-histories doesn't work?

Comment: It works, but it puts all the contents of the repo A at the root of the repo B, not in a subfolder..

Comment: Funnily enough I have just come across a situation where I would like to do this. I'll get back to you if I find a solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20974621/7831758 worked for me. Create repo BigRepo in a separate folder tree from RepoOne etc and do as instructed. It does create the history in another branch but I'm happy with that.

Comment: Doing a git rebase -i HEAD~3 after each merge seems to merge the histories into the master branch