# How to combine two git repos, preserving the history of both, and the hashes of one?

Tags: git, repository

## What I've got

I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161910/merge-two-git-repositories-and-keep-the-master-history) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292219/merge-two-git-repos-and-keep-the-history) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694961/merge-two-git-repositories-consistent-history) [combining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another) [repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371150/moving-git-repository-content-to-another-repository-preserving-history). I'm almost there, but I'm missing something.

I have two repositories `current-repo`, which published and shared, and `old-repo` which is not. I have the only copy. Their histories look something like

```
                         1--2--3--4--5  <= current-repo
                         =
                content is the same
                         =
old-repo =>  a--b--c--d--e
```

## What I want

Ideally, by combining the two repos, I'd get a repo with a history like

```
1. a--b--c--d--1--2--3--4--5  <= notice, duplicate old entry "e" is dropped"
```

I'd also settle for the following:

```
2. a--b--c--d--e--1--2--3--4--5            <= duplicate content in "e" and "1"
3. foo--bar--baz--buz--1--2--3--4--5       <= like #1 above, but rehashed "old" history
4. foo--bar--baz--buz--bif--1--2--3--4--5  <= like #4, but "bif" and "1" have duplicate content
```

## What I've tried

I can get to this point (locally) with

```
cd ~/current-repo
git remote add -f old-repo ~/old-repo
git replace -f --graft 1 d
```

Now, it's my understanding that at this point I have to push/pull `refs/replace/*`. I don't want my users to have to do this step.

The `git graft` (and maybe some `git replace`) solutions that I saw, had a `git filter-branch` step. I tried this, and also `git rebase`-ing, but only the hashes from the `current-repo` history were re-written. I also, don't want this. I don't care if the history from the `old-repo` get's re-hashed. As I mentioned, that repo isn't published and shared. Basically, the next time my users did a `git fetch`, they'd get a bunch of old history, in addition to whatever "new" history they were missing.

## tl;dr

I want to combine two git repos, maintaining a linear history, and maintaining the hashes of the "newer" repository. How do I get to a repository with my chosen history (above) or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

No, it cannot be done.

**Details**

Preserving the hashing while adding more history at the beginning is not possible, by design.

The sha1 hash of a commit is based on the idea of a cryptographic signature: it hashes not only the commit and its contents, date, committer and all that, but it also hashes the parents in, which means that it hashes the entire history leading to that commit.

Thus, there is no way to change the history without changing the hash of every commit whose history was extended (or modified in any other way).

Comment: I thought as much. Oh well... gives me an excuse to reorganize the repo!