# Merge two Git repositories without breaking file history or releases

Tags: git, github

So I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history) and it worked fine. But I also want to keep the releases from both repositories. Is it possible to do this?

Basically I have 2 repos, where repo 1 is an older version of repo 2. I want to clean up my GitHub to only have one.

Comment: You can create any history and content you want.  The only thing you can't do is pass it off as something different than it is.  The existing histories have their own IDs, so long as you're happy with new IDs for the new history you can call it whatever you want.  Do you want the content and ancestry in repo 2 to appear as a descendant of the current repo 1 tip, or what? Draw the ancestry structure you have, and the ancestry structure you want, and describe where you want the contents to be in this new history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by releases, you are refering to GitHub releases, those are [based on a tag](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release).

If you have merged the history of the two repos, [following your link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20974621/6309), the tags of the second repo have been preserved.
You can then fetch from that second original repo the [release by its tag](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-release-by-tag-name), and create a new one, for that same tag, this time in the new merged repo.
This has to be scripted, in order to repeat the process for all the tags/releases of the merged repo.