# Remove actual git repo after adding as submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

i'm new so please bear with me! I had made two repos on git, lets call them `FRONTEND` & `BACKEND`. I didn't like that these 2 repositories, which belong to the same App/Project, should be in different git repos. So, I made a parent `CMS` repository and `git submodule`ed `FRONTEND` & `BACKEND` to it. But on GitHub, I can still see the initial repos and also the submoduled repos in the `CMS`. I don't want to lose my GitHub commits. Is there a way to consolidate the repos into a single repo with multiple folders without losing the commits?

Comment: You can *create* a new repo with the shared history of both, but that will be unrelated (i.e. not compatible with) any of the 3 others. Is that what you want?

Comment: yeah, so the magic word was `shared history`. I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history) answer. Thank you so much for your help. Since, this is somehow a duplicate question, should I remove this? @JoachimSauer

Comment: Marking this as a duplicate might help others help the other answer as well if they phrase their search as you did, so marking this as a duplicate is preferable to just removing this question.