# Maintain git history when merging two repos into one

Tags: git, github, repository, versioning

I have two Github repos that I would like to be merged into one repo while maintaining the git history (for git blame) for both of these original repos. However i would like that future branches contain the changes from both repos in this new one

```js
# Original Set up

- Repo 1
- Repo 2


# What I want to achieve

New Master Repo ->
  - Repo 1
  - Repo 2
```

In 'What I want to achieve' I want to be able to see the file history of `Repo 1` and `Repo 2` inside of `New Master Repo`. For instance, going into `Repo 1` should still show me `git blame` info before I had merged those two repos.

I also should be able to make a new branch in `New Master Repo` where changes from `Repo 1` and `Repo 2` can be `git add --all` and `git commit` together in this one branch.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you pass through this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history

Comment: Thank you. My question was a duplicate and this solution solves it.