How can I completely replace a remote repo with a local repo while preserving both commit histories?
I have two separate repos:

A remote GitHub repo with an existing commit history, issues, and a wiki.
A local git repo with its own distinct commit history.

I want to replace the contents of the remote repository with those of the local repository, effectively making the remote an exact copy of the local one.

The commit history of the remote repository should remain intact.
The commit history of the local repository should be appended to the remote repository’s history (i.e., the remote’s latest commit should be followed by the local repository’s first commit, and so on).
The remote repo’s issues & wiki should remain untouched.

I have not made any attempts at this as I do not want to risk losing anything.
Edit: All commits in the local repo have timestamps AFTER the most recent commit in the remote repo.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories ?

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history ?

When you say "The commit history of the local repository should be appended to the remote repository’s history", I have to ask about the state of the files: is the worktree the same in the last commit on remote and the first commit on local? Or was it edited in between? Tell us more about how the local repo builds on the remote one.  (And yeah, please also check those suggested duplicates, and report back here if they solve your issue.)

@joanis Not edited in between; I have updated the original post to reflect this. I haven't tried any of the suggested solutions yet but the official answer of the second linked thread seems promising; however I think the simplest solution to my specific issue is just to create a commit where I delete all files in the remote repo, then copy all local files to the remote repo, commit, and done. Do you know of any side effects to this?

Your last comment sounds like you do not make or know the difference between "repository state" and "commit history". Why would you do what you suggest in the comment (delete all, commit, add all, commit) to achieve what you are asking for in the question? That just does not make sense.

@j6t forgive my naivety, I realize that would not solve this issue at all. That would just create one single commit without preserving the entire commit history of the local repo. My understanding of git is indeed very limited, but I have some time to thoroughly review the two duplicate threads tonight and will report back with what worked or didn't.

This ended up being my solution, since my files were different enough that I didn't have to resolve many merge conflicts:
Add the remote repo to the local repo:
git remote add remote-repo ../remote-repo
git fetch remote-repo
git checkout -b remote-repo-history remote-repo/main

Merge histories:
git checkout main
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories remote-repo-history
git checkout --ours .
# here I needed to first remove all my remote repo files
git add .
git commit -m "Resolved conflicts, prioritizing local files"

Check merge is successful:
git log --oneline --graph --all
Then I deleted the branch and pushed:
git branch -d remote-repo-history
git remote add origin <new-remote-url>
git push -u origin main

Disclaimer that I am very unfamiliar with git and this solution is likely not elegant whatsoever but it works to fulfill all my requirements in the original post. I should also note that this is a solo project and I do not know how others would be affected. I do not recommend following this.

+1 for using git merge --allow-unrelated-histories. Given the vague description of the desired outcome, this does sound like a viable solution. There may not even be a better solution to achieve the goal.

@j6t Noted, thank you for your feedback!
