# filter-branch to remove extra directory

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm migrating several Subversion repositories to Git, but they were set up a bit weird: the standard trunk/branches/tags structure lives within several subdirectories of the repository. /branches and /tags are both empty, so the git-svn import ended up with only the trunk directories.

```
svn/
  proj1/
    trunk/
      src/
  proj2/
    trunk/
      src/
```

I would like to use `git filter-branch` to remove the extra trunk folders but leave the rest intact:

```
svn/
  proj1/
    src/
  proj2/
    src/
```

Based on the last [example in the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_examples), this is what I have so far:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
    'git ls-files -s | sed "s-/trunk/-/-" |
        GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
            git update-index --index-info &&
     mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
```

It seems to me that the `sed` is doing its job, as this input:

```
100644 fa3dcf79717e9aca85ad745078a2fb2a2ce2b900 0       proj1/trunk/src/file1.txt
```

Produces this output:

```
100644 fa3dcf79717e9aca85ad745078a2fb2a2ce2b900 0       proj1/src/file1.txt
```

However, when I run the whole command, I get the following error:

```
Rewrite e00c119cfb755f741dc0e17c36d36bc2ddd27562 (1/42)mv: cannot stat `/c/dev/R
epo/.git-rewrite/t/../index.new': No such file or directory
index filter failed: git ls-files -s | sed "s-/trunk/-/-" |
            GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
                git update-index --index-info &&
         mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
```

Any ideas? I'm using git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0 on Windows.

**Update:** Now using git version 1.9.0.msysgit.0, a similar situation yields a different error (note `.git-rewrite` does not exist before executing the command):

```
rm: cannot remove `c:/Path/to/svn/.git-rewrite/revs': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove directory `c:/Path/to/svn/.git-rewrite': Directory not empty
```

The same fix ultimately worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out based on a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories/3336302#3336302). It seems to be an issue with how git-svn represents "empty" (directory-only) commits. It works fine if I start at a normal commit:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
    'git ls-files -s | sed "s-/trunk/-/-" |
        GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
            git update-index --index-info &&
     mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' 83df928c..HEAD
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. That's good to know. I guess `git update-index` doesn't actually create an index file if it gets nothing from `git ls-files`; it doesn't seem to be able to produce an empty index from empty input.

Comment: Did nothing for me.  Looking for a more general solution.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that my specific answer to my specific question doesn't answer your more general question.

Comment: In case anyone has a similar situation to me, it was slightly different from OP: the initial commit in my git repository was empty (e.g. commited using 'git commit --allow-empty'). Running filter-branch from the commit after the empty commit to HEAD fixed the issue: e.g. FIRST_COMMIT..HEAD. Empty commits that are not the initial commit didn't seem to cause any issues.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, however I am new to git, and I wonder if that `83df928c..HEAD` is a part of the command you propose for this problem, or is it something very specific to your problem?

Comment: 83df928c is just a reference to the first "real" commit - replace that with the SHA of your first non-empty commit, and you should be good to go.

More generally, `foo..bar` means "commits from `foo` to `bar`, and `HEAD` is essentially "here" (what's currently checked out). So `83df928c..HEAD` means "commits from `83df928c` to here".

Comment: Worked - but I cannot run it a second time - `rm: cannot remove .git-rewrite’: Directory not empty` any idea what the problem is?

Comment: @BenjaminPeter try `rm -rf .git-rewrite`, the temp folder where `filter-branch` stores stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I can't see anything wrong with what you're running, and it works fine for me in an example repository:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/bcampbel/tmp/git-subdir/.git/
$ mkdir -p proj1/trunk
$ echo "hello" > proj1/trunk/test.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
[master (root-commit) cd431f3] initial commit
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 proj1/trunk/test.txt
$ echo "foo" > proj1/trunk/another.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "add a file"
[master 84139f2] add a file
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 proj1/trunk/another.txt
$ git filter-branch --index-filter \
>     'git ls-files -s | sed "s-/trunk/-/-" |
>         GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
>             git update-index --index-info &&
>      mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
Rewrite 84139f26c7921721190b3c5dd57e2b49a41034aa (2/2)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
$ ls proj1/
another.txt test.txt
```

It appears that for some reason, the `index.new` file did not get written out on your system, or could not be read by the `mv` command. I am not sure why this would be, but I wonder if it may be due to the fact that you're using msysgit on Windows. Do you have a Linux box or Mac that you could try it on?