# Split an ikiwiki

Tags: git, wiki, ikiwiki

I am trying to split an ikiwiki into two wikis.

Suppose I have an ikiwiki called myiki (compare [this question from ikiwiki.info](http://ikiwiki.info/forum/Split_a_wiki/)), which contains the pages

```
pageA1,pageA2,...,pageB1,pageB2,...
```

now I want to have two wikis called `myikiA` and `myikiB`, such that:

- `myikiA` contains `pageA1,pageA2,...`
  The history of `myikiA` should contain the whole history of those pages, but no history of `pageB1,pageB2,...`

and:

- `myikiB` contains pageB1,pageB2,...
  The history of `myikiB` should contain the whole history of those pages but no history of `pageA1,pageA2,...`

In a first step I made a copy of my `scrdir` and tried to remove a page named `foo` like this (note that in the `scrdir` there are files called `foo.mdwn` and directories `foo` as well).
To do so, I did this command:

```
sudo git filter-branch --tree-filter 'find . -name foo* -exec rm -r -f  {} \;' --prune-empty -f HEAD

Rewrite 3cbc4646145e31cf7ce23d5e8397baaebab64c60 (179/1439)find: `./index/testdir/foo': No such file or directory
tree filter failed: find . -name foo* -exec rm -r -f  {} \;
```

Any Idea what's wrong with it?

Is there a way to give a list of pages and split the wiki as described above?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677766/filter-branch-to-remove-extra-directory help or apply in your case?

Comment: Hm. Thanks, however I don't see, how to apply it to this situation (I am a git newbie). git-ls-files seems not to work recusively!?

Comment: Yes, I was just wandering if the '`git update-index --index-info`' bit might improve the situation.

Comment: @VonC Could you post the complete command I should try instead of that in my post?

Comment: It's really important for me to solve this issue, any idea is welcome...

Comment: Sorry, but my initial idea don't apply to your `git filter-branch` command. That would have been `sudo git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git update-index --index-info && find . -name foo* -exec rm -r -f  {} \;' --prune-empty -f HEAD`

Comment: @VonC Yes, gives the same error.

Comment: Since there are no answers up to now in spite of the bounty, it might be a good idea to move this question to another stackexchange site. What do you thin, which site is appropriate for this question?

Answer (score 1):

When `find` finds `foo/`, it calls `rm -rf` on it and then tries to enter it to find more files. You can cause find to remove the directory and then ignore it using `-prune`.

`find . -name foo* -exec rm -r -f {} \; -prune`

Comment: Thanks, now I get: `Rewrite 9ed693bf5ed887beac89b482ba8dcf971429838a (97/1492)find: `./index/foo.mdwn': No such file or directory
tree filter failed: git update-index --index-info && find . -name foo\* -exec rm -r -f {} \; -prune`

Comment: Hmm, you might get away with `find . -name foo.mdwn -delete -o -name foo -type d -exec rm -rf {} \; -prune`? Something along these lines. It's also worth pointing out that the 'foo*' you are using may get expanded by the shell, so you might need to toss it in quotes.