# How to merge history from unrelated repositories

Tags: git, svn

I have an old project on SVN organized like this:

- /some/sub-directories/a/trunk/foo
- /some/sub-directories/b/trunk/foo
- /some/sub-directories/c/trunk/foo

I migrated using GitHub tools `git-import-svn-raw` these three repositories under three Git repositories:

- a.git
- b.git
- c.git

I used this command to get rid of the path

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter \
/some/sub-directories/a/trunk/foo master
```

Now I would like to import the history of all these three projects into the very same repository where I have three directories `a`, `b`, `c`.

```
bundle.git/
   a/
   b/
   c/
```

The idea is not to merge the sub-tree but to interlace the history of each individual sub-directories together.

Is that possible?

Note: It would have been easier to convert the whole SVN repository into a single repository, but it doesn't work. I get many issues with the `git-import-svn-raw` tool. The same issue appear with `git svn clone --stdlayout` with requires a single repository which is not the case. I have also tried `svn2git` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: If these are truly unrelated projects, I would suggest against putting them into one repository. Git is not Subversion and some old habits should go away when making the switch.

Comment: Indeed, there are perfectly related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against using "bundle" as the name of a repo, because `bundle` means something else to git.  To avoid confusing the issue I'll use your terms throughout this answer, but I would use a different name.

So it's easy to get all the commits into the same repo.

```
cd bundle.git
git remote add a ../a.git
git remote add b ../b.git
git remote add c ../c.git
git fetch --all
```

Now you have refs like `remote/a/master`, `remote/b/master`, `remote/c/master`.

```
A1 -- A2 -- A3 -- A4 <--(a/master)

B1 -- B2 -- B3 -- B4 <--(b/master)

C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- C4 <--(c/master)

(master)
```

Note that I'm assuming you started with `master` having no commits ("unborn" branch) and it is still in that state here.

Next, getting a single commit with the combined content would also not be difficult.  For example you could do this:

```
git reset --hard a/master
get merge --allow-unrelated-histories b/master
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories c/master
```

which would give you

```
               (a/master)
                   v
A1 -- A2 -- A3 -- A4 -- M1 ------------- M2 <--(master)
                       /                /
B1 --- B2 --- B3 --- B4 <--(b/master)  /
                                      /
C1 -------- C2 -------- C3 -------- C4 <--(c/master)
```

This history is complete and correct, but the historical commits are not interleaved and they don't have combined content (`TREE` objects).  So if you check out `B3` you will not see what `a` or `c` looked like at the corresponding time, for example.

That may be good enough.  The output from `log` will default to reverse-chronological, and you can provide ordering options to influence exactly how this history is ordered (see `git log` docs).  But it's not what you asked for...

So for the next step you could

```
git rebase -i --root master
```

This will bring up a "TODO" list that shows all the commits; but you'd have to manually figure out the order in which you want them interleaved.  (The default order follows each branch, one at a time.)  So that could be quite tedious.  You can use `git log` output to figure out the correct order, and then re-arrange the TODO list accordingly.

**UPDATE** : It occurs to me that I should add some caveats about the `rebase` step.

First, the above only speaks explicitly about `master` branches.  Of course each repo could have additional branches, and you'd have to decide how you want those reflected.  Maybe you would decide that the branch point (the first commit from `master` reachable from the branch) should be unchanged, and the branch would simply not have changes from the other repos interleaved into it (assuming this wouldn't lead to branch name collisions).  Or maybe you would decide to combine corresponding branches from each source repo in some way.

Second, if there are merges in the original histories, then you'll have to decide how to handle them in the rebase.  This is especially a problem if the merges either contain conflict resolutions, or are "evil merges" (i.e. merges that introduce changes relative to the default merge result).  The above procedure will try to produce a single, linear history.  If that's not what you want, then it's quite difficult to make this work, because should you tell `rebase` to keep the merges, then it will keep the three histories separate as well.  (Besides, `--preserve-merges` doesn't mix well with `--interactive` / `-i`.)

So the above works for relatively simple histories, and for more complex histories it may just not be a practical thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/34861819/933106 for another approach to "zipper up" two repositories based on their commit timestamp.