# Merging two git repositories as well as their tags

Tags: git

I have two git repositories A and B, which both correspond to a library. Library B depends on library A. The repositories both have the same set of tags, corresponding to versions. These tags/versions are linearly ordered. The build of version V of library B is done by matching it with a build of version V of library A. These repositories really should have been a single repository from the start.

How can I combine the repositories into a single repository C which has the same tags as A and B, and for a given tag V in C the libraries A and B are both in version V?

The repository A should go to a root directory A, and similarly for B, so there can be no conflicts.

I'm thinking it should be possible to

- replay commits from library A up to tag V,
- replay commits from library B up to tag V,
- tag repository C with V.
- continue the same process of interleaving replays up to the next tag, until there are no more tags.

I'm also thinking the process may not be unique, but I'm ok with any history which satisfies the requirements. History should be preserved for both repositories.

Answer (score 0):

History, in any Git repository, *is* the set of commits in the repository.

The commits are numbered, with a *unique* number that cannot be changed or re-used; new commits get a *new* unique number that is not re-using an old number and cannot be changed.  So any process that builds a new repository from existing commits by combining things will necessarily produce a *new and different history*.

That's fine—there's nothing wrong with this—but don't expect the history to be *preserved*.  It will be transformed.  If you can establish consistent rules for making the transformation, you can later re-combine updated versions of the input repositories to get the same commits you got last time *plus* new commits.

There are some tools for this but there is no Standard Git Tool.  See [Dietrech Epp's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74280912/1256452).

Comment: I'm not sure I use terminology right, but by preserving history I mean that I can see the commit history, so that it is just not one blob of "Library A added" and "Library B added".

Comment: That just means that your "replay" process (your transformation work) needs to have some sort of rules for interleaving the commits from the input repositories. See the other question, which is basically the same.

Comment: So I should use Copybara? I was there was someone who could give the needed steps for it.

Comment: Dunno, I've never used any of these tools myself.