# When should git orphaned branches be used?

Tags: git

Git can host multiple DAGs in the same repo with `git checkout --orphan` command. A frequently cited use case this feature of git is to keep separate a branch for docs or the GitHub `gh-pages` orphaned branch for creating a static website.

Are there other reasons to use orphaned branches in git?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another possible use of this is for combining multiple repositories into one. A few examples:

- http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0506/5511.html
- http://jasonkarns.com/blog/merge-two-git-repositories-into-one/
- [Combining multiple git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories)

In these cases you will have two separate DAGs in the same repository before they are merged into a single unified tree. Thus this is not as much a long-term use, but an action that will temporarily pass through the state of having separate DAGs in the same repository.

Answer (score 8):

Another use case by the [`git` online documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> This can be useful when you want to publish the tree from a commit
>   without exposing its full history. You might want to do this to
>   publish an open source branch of a project whose current tree is
>   "clean", but whose full history contains proprietary or otherwise encumbered bits of code.

Answer (score 0):

The [Git project repository mirror on GitHub](https://github.com/git/git) has a `todo` branch where the maintainer has some notes and apparently scripts which helps him make announcements like the status updates for the project (“What’s Cooking”).[1]

```
> ls
add-by      CB                    cook                   dodoc.sh            git-topic.perl  KO          people           RB              Release    round    taboo.perl  WCBCC
amlook      Checklist.txt         Count                  Doit                Gitweb          Linus       post-applypatch  README.cooking  RelSave    RP       TODO        whats-cooking.txt
Announce    CheckPush             count-contributors.sh  DoKernelOrg         GRADUATED       MaintNotes  pre-applypatch   Reintegrate     RelSign    SE       UWC         WI
AT          check-topic-merges    cycle-run              Dothem              info            Make        ProjectContact   RelBuild        RelStat    SR       V           worklog
candidates  compare-cooking.perl  docbuild-8.sh          genMaintNotes.perl  jc.png          ML          pushall          RelClean        RelUpload  Summary  WC
```

The last message that was sent out can be viewed in `whats-cooking.txt`.

So this isn’t a “separate a branch for docs” (that stuff is on the main branch) but rather a separate branch for managing announcements. And perhaps other stuff.

Here is the first commit on this branch, which of course is a root commit (no parents):

```
commit 1bd90415deccc4562e0fb4d0f8e58140aa687ac1
Author: Junio C Hamano <junkio@cox.net>
Date:   Fri Aug 26 00:32:15 2005 -0700

    Keep track of to-do document.

    This is written in a form of to-do list for me, so if I say
    "accept patch", it means I do not currently plan to do that
    myself.  People interested in seeing it materialize please take
    a hint.

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <junkio@cox.net>
```

† 1: As of commit [acb9ef215eb2](https://github.com/git/git/tree/acb9ef215eb2) (What's cooking (2023/03 #01), 2023-03-01)