# Create new Main repo. Add two separate repos into Main repo but not merge them and without losing history

Tags: git, github

I am creating an app and have been working on the Front-end and Back-end in separate repos. Both have been committed to GitHub.

Now I want to create a new repo called Main and move both Front-end and Back-end repos into the Main repo. I want to keep them separate and not merge them. I also want to preserve the log and commit history of both repos. Both repos have had branches and then merged later into master.

I see posts showing how to merge repos together into one which keeps the histories but I do not want to merge them.

I am not looking for submodules nor are they orphaned branches.

Comment: Related: [stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the uses cases for git orphaned branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202705/what-are-the-uses-cases-for-git-orphaned-branches)

Comment: Why do you want a new repo "Main" if everything is separated? Are you asking for [`sumbodules`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Comment: Not asking for sumbodules, orphaned branches but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on this site: https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/

### Merging Two Git Repositories Into One Repository Without Losing File History

#### The basic idea is that we follow these steps:

1. Create a new empty repository New.
2. Make an initial commit because we need one before we do a merge.
3. Add a remote to old repository OldA.
4. Merge OldA/master to New/master.
5. Make a subdirectory OldA.
6. Move all files into subdirectory OldA.
7. Commit all of the file moves.
8. Repeat 3-6 for OldB.

#### A Powershell script for these steps might look like this:*

1. Assume the current directory is where we want the new repository to be created. Create the new repository

   - `git init`
2. Before we do a merge, we have to have an initial commit, so we’ll make a dummy commit

   - `dir > deleteme.txt`
   - `git add .`
   - `git commit -m “Initial dummy commit”`
3. Add a remote for and fetch the old repo

   - `git remote add -f old_a <OldA repo URL>`
4. Merge the files from old_a/master into new/master

   - `git merge old_a/master`
5. Clean up our dummy file because we don’t need it any more

   - `git rm .\deleteme.txt`
   - `git commit -m “Clean up initial file”`
6. Move the old_a repo files and folders into a subdirectory so they don’t collide with the other repo coming later

   - `mkdir old_a`
   - `dir –exclude old_a | %{git mv $_.Name old_a}`
7. Commit the move

   - `git commit -m “Move old_a files into subduer”`
8. Do the same thing for old_b

   - `git remote add -f old_b <OldB repo URL>`
   - `git merge old_b/master`
   - `mkdir old_b`
   - `dir –exclude old_a,old_b | %{git mv $_.Name old_b}`
   - `git commit -m “Move old_b files into subduer”`