# Git workflow with both orphaned and non-orphaned branches

Tags: git, orphan

I've been reading up on Orphaned git branches. My situation is described in the git manual under [checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) which I found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50605543/238882)

> This can be useful when you want to publish the tree from a commit without exposing its full history. You might want to do this to publish an open source branch of a project whose current tree is "clean", but whose full history contains proprietary or otherwise encumbered bits of code.

However, I'd like to *work on that open source branch* not just publish it. That is, I've pushed an orphan to GitHub, remote name `origin`. Our full history remains internal, remote name `internal`. On my local machine, I'd like to do development work pushing and pulling from `origin`, building on the orphaned branch, and occasionally our team would like to copy (push? merge?) our local & origin branches to `internal`.

I haven't found a question and answer that addresses this use case. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

You can try creating your local orphan branch

```
 git checkout --orphan orphan_name
```

pushing it into github

```
 git push origin orphan_name
```

then create feature branch from the `orphan_name`

```
 git checkout -b open-source-feature
```

create some change and commit

```
 git commit -m "Open source feature"
```

push it into GitHub

```
 git push origin open-source-feature
```

and you can also create `internal-feature` from `open-source-feature`

```
 git checkout -b internal-feature origin/open-source-feature
```

and rebase it on top of `internal/develop` (for example)

```
 git rebase internal/develop
```

and push it to the internal repository

```
 git push internal internal-feature
```

Comment: Thanks for this. One additional complication: How would we go about merging in changes from `internal` branches (but without their history)?

Comment: You can create the branch off of the internal and rebase it on top of the origin branch. You can pass --interactive flag to squash commits or change the commit messages