# Merging git repositories of different languages

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combining multiple git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories)

I'm recoding an application from PHP to Ruby. Is there a way to merge the two repositories while keeping the commits of each version? Ideally it would be something like this

**[ruby repository]**

```
commit 1
commit 2
commit 3
...
```

**[php repository]**

```
...
commit 54
commit 55
commit 56
```

**[new repository]**

```
...
commit 54
commit 55
commit 56
commit 1
commit 2
commit 3
...
```

Comment: What do your integers represent - the SHA hash of the commit, or just an ordering?  The former is not possible (commit SHAs take ancestry into account so will change for one of the repos); the latter is.

Comment: Just the order of the commits

Comment: So basically you just want to apply all commits from ruby repository on top of php repository, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rebase ruby/master on top of php/master:

```
git rebase php/master ruby/master
```