# GIT - Remove old commit history before filter-branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I would like to merge 4 repositories into one using the method declared on this question: [Combining multiple git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories)

The Problem is the whole process takes ~3 Hours to be finished, because one of those repositories has about 26000 commits since Year 2008.

Is there any way to process only commits since 2013 e.g. using --commit-filter?
 Thank you.

Comment: Are your running `git filter-branch` on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You could create separate clones of your stitched repos with a limited graph depth:

```
git clone --depth 100 /local/path/a /tmp/to-stitch/a
git clone --depth 120 /local/path/b /tmp/to-stitch/b
git clone --depth 200 /local/path/c /tmp/to-stitch/c
```

and then stitch `/tmp/to-stitch/a`, `/tmp/to-stitch/b` and `/tmp/to-stitch/c`. The first commits in each repo would have the squashed patches from the repo's root commit until `HEAD~<n>`.

Comment: Thank you, but as I mentioned in my question, is it possible to limit the entries based on committed time and just use commits since 2013?

Comment: Since `git-stitch-repo` doesn't seem to have parameters to select the revision range, it seems you can't.

Comment: You can try this to find the number of commits (e.g. your `--depth` parameter): `git log --since=2013-01-01 --oneline | wc -l`

Comment: As I understand, git-stich-repo is a perl script which must first be installed using CPAN. As I have a Jenkins Server to execute and run the script without having access to install Perl or CPAN on it, is there an alternative to get around this Problem using pure Linux and GIT Commands?

Comment: Yes, there is: install `git-stitch-repo` on your workstation. Other than that you could read `git-stitch-repo`'s source code and enter the git commands yourself. But I don't see why you would want to do that.