# migrate git repositories into another

Tags: git, github, repository, git-push, git-pull

I have a repository A and B and want to migrate both repositories into C,
I tried below steps

```
git clone --bare <A-url>
cd to the A.git directory
git push --mirror <C-url>
```

Now C has same copy of A

```
git clone --bare <B-url>
cd to the B.git directory
git push --mirror <C-url>
```

Here repository C is having only folders and files from repo B and the content from repository A removed
Is there any way to persist/retain the files in repository C ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining multiple git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+combine+repositories

Answer (score 0):

Use the `git subtree add` command like in this doc: https://git-memo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subtree.html#adding-a-subtree-to-a-project