# Copying one git repo to another repo with history

Tags: git, azure-devops

How to copy one repo entirely to another repo with history.

I don't want to use fork or mirroring options, I tried out branch-filter options but it is limited to one directory. 
**git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter /../RepoA/dire1**

I was referring below url
https://medium.com/@ayushya/move-directory-from-one-repository-to-another-preserving-git-history-d210fa049d4b/

```
Example:
Source      Target             Requirement
------      ----              -------------------
RepoA       RepoB(new Repo)   Copy entire history  
  - Dir1     - Dir1
  - Dir2     - Dir2
```

Could you please suggest?

Comment: Could something here help? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+combine+multiple+repositories

Comment: `submodule` or `subtree`? I'm not sure what is your question. Maybe It would be better if you explain why or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi  was below answer helpful to you? how did it go with above case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the `--index-filter` instead of the `--subdirectory-filter`.

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter \
    'git ls-files -s | sed "s#\t#&RepoA/#" |
     GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
     git update-index --index-info &&
     mv $GIT_INDEX_FILE.new $GIT_INDEX_FILE' HEAD
```

Please checkout [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories) for more information.

If RepoB is a fresh new repo. Yon can also try below commands. Clone RepoA to local machine, remove the remote origin of RepoA, then add the remote url to RepoB. see below example:

```
git clone http:/url/repoA
cd repoA
git pull origin branchName
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin http:/url/repoB
git push -u origin --all
```

You can also try using git submodule. Check the [git document](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for more information.