# Combining GitHub repos

Tags: git, github

I have just completed a Coding Bootcamp and have each assignment in a separate repo.  Is there a simple way to combine these in one master repo? Will I lose my contributions if done this way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining multiple git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories)

Comment: Once you have combined your repos into a single repo following the answers to the questions linked above, you can have a single GitHub repo as its remote and delete the other ones.