# How to stack two commits histories over each other?

Tags: git, git-commit

I started a project in one repository (V1), and then started on top of it is code, other repository (V2) by downloading the first repository as Zip file and committing from zero.

the last commit in repository V1 is: May 27, 5:00 PM

the first commit in repository V2 is: May 28 3:00 PM

How can we stack the two commit stacks on top of each other.. into one repository? so that all commit history will be presented in one repository.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for  [combining-multiple-git-repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories) OR [how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)