# How to get all commit history from private forked repository?

Tags: git, github

I want to get all github commit history from another repository to my new github repository.

**Scenario:**

That repository could be:

- From my another repository
- From contributed projects such as my company project
- From forked project which one is in private mode

In my case, I worked on my company project. Which repository is in private mode on github. Now I want all code base from that repository with git commit. Though I can clone that project and upload it new repository without commit history but I want also commit history. Does it possible?

Comment: I dont understand - cant you just press fork on gitlab?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: You add a remote to your local repo that points to the new repo in github, then push any branch into the new remote.

Comment: @CasperBang I updated question. 
 I worked on my company project. Which repository is in private mode on github. Now I want all code base from that repository with git commit. Though I can clone that project and upload it new repository without commit history but I want also commit history. Does it possible?

Comment: @LeGEC I updated question.
 I worked on my company project. Which repository is in private mode on github. Now I want all code base from that repository with git commit. Though I can clone that project and upload it new repository without commit history but I want also commit history. Does it possible?

Comment: @eftshift0  I worked on my company project. Which repository is in private mode on github. Now I want all code base from that repository with git commit. Though I can clone that project and upload it new repository without commit history but I want also commit history. Does it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining multiple git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories)

Comment: If you can _clone_ it (which implies you get history along with it), you can push branches (and their histories, like any other push) into a different _remote_.

Comment: @iamtheasad : A commit always comes with its complete history : it contains a link to its parent, which in turn contains a link to its parent, etc ... when you push a branch or a commit, you also push its history with it

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is wrong.

> Though I can clone that project and upload it new repository without commit history

A normal clone of a repository contains the full history.

*Please not that making a public fork/clone of a private repository seems to go against the wishes of the owner of the original repository and it may be illegal*

Comment: I think you know that from another repositorie's .git file won't support in new repository.
So deleted the old .git file and uploaded it new new github repository. Hope I am clear?!

Comment: Deleting .git **folder** makes the folder stop being a git repository. Why did you delete it? That's where the history is.

Comment: On my new repository already have a .git folder so I deleted old one. 
I want new repository's .git folder to merge with the old .git repository.

Comment: In this case follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories

Comment: Thank you for your awareness. But it's completely ok in my company policy.